# Echo %path% on separate lines

Tags: powershell, path, cmd

Using the Windows command prompt, can I *echo %path%* and get the resulting paths on separate rows?

Something like this, but for Windows:

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
```

Can I do this with vanilla [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) or do I need PowerShell or JavaScript scripting?

Example echo %path% output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;
```

Desired output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;
```

Comment: Related: [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141344/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-path/8046515#8046515) to *[How to check if a directory exists in %PATH%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141344)* deals with all the complications of using simple text parsing for the content of environment variable `path`.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Try:

```
 ($env:Path).Replace(';',"`n")
```

or

```
$env:path.split(";")
```

Comment: What is wrong with the following?
powershell -Command ($env:Path).Replace(';',"`n")

Comment: PowerShell has `-replace` operator: `$env:Path -replace ';',"`n"`

Comment: Will fail with quoted paths that contain semicolons.

Comment: @Joey: What should I do instead then?

Comment: @Eric: You could use one of the more complicated regexes used for CSV instead, or use a parser. Or hope that no one uses semicolons in paths that appear in `$Env:PATH` since everyone gets it wrong anyway ...

Comment: @Joey: So there's no native way to split the path in the same way as it is done when resolving executables, without resorting to string manipulation? That's just dumb!

Comment: @Eric: How frequently do you write scripts that need every item in `$Env:PATH`? I haven't needed that ever so far, and I guess most other people didn't either.

Comment: @Joey: I'm more pointing out that internally there must be an implementation of that for `get-command` to work, so exposing that implementation would be easy

Comment: @stej Use triple backticks: ```$env:Path -replace ';',"`n"```

Answer (score 46):

Fewer keystrokes using either the split **operator** or **method**

```
$env:Path -split ';'
$env:Path.split(';')
```

Comment: Will fail with quoted paths that contain semicolons.

Comment: This looks nice with a sort: `($env:Path).Split(";") | Sort-Object`

Answer (score 12):

This works for me (in a cmd window):

```
powershell -Command ($env:Path).split(';')
```

Comment: Does it work for quoted paths that contain semicolons?

Comment: @PeterMortensen no.