# 'Pretty print' windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, path

I want to run a simple one-liner in the Windows CMD prompt to print my `%PATH%` variable, one entry per line.

I tried this: `for /f "delims=;" %a in ("%path%") do echo %a` but this only prints the first entry:

```
Z:\>for /f "delims=;" %a in ("%path%") do echo %a

Z:\>echo c:\python25\.
c:\python25\.
```

Also as you can see from the output above, this is also printing the `echo %a` command as well as the output. Is there any way to stop this?

If I try a similar command, I get all the entries, but still get the `echo %a` output spamming the results. I don't understand why the following prints all entries, but my attempt on `%PATH%` doesn't. I suspect I don't understand the `/F` switch.

```
Z:\>for %a in (1 2 3) do echo %a

Z:\>echo 1
1

Z:\>echo 2
2

Z:\>echo 3
3
```

Comment: **PowerShell**: `$env:path.split(";")`

Comment: @ROMANIA_engineer - Since the question asks for a command that works in the CMD shell, here is a way to use your elegant answer from there: `powershell -Command ($env:Path).split(';')`. To make it still more readable, you can add sorting: `powershell -Command ($env:Path).split(';') | sort`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The simple way is to use

```
for %a in ("%path:;=";"%") do @echo %~a
```

This works for all without `;` in the path and without `"` around a single element
Tested with path=C:\qt\4.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files;C:\documents & Settings

But a "always" solution is a bit complicated
**EDIT: Now a working variant**

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "var=foo & bar;baz<>gak;"semi;colons;^&embedded";foo again!;throw (in) some (parentheses);"unmatched ;-)";(too"

set "var=%var:"=""%"
set "var=%var:^=^^%"
set "var=%var:&=^&%"
set "var=%var:|=^|%"
set "var=%var:<=^<%"
set "var=%var:>=^>%"

set "var=%var:;=^;^;%"
rem ** This is the key line, the missing quote is intended
set var=%var:""="%
set "var=%var:"=""%"

set "var=%var:;;="";""%"
set "var=%var:^;^;=;%"
set "var=%var:""="%"
set "var=%var:"=""%"
set "var=%var:"";""=";"%"
set "var=%var:"""="%"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in ("!var!") do (
    endlocal
    echo %%~a
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
)
```

What did I do there?
I tried to solve the main problem: that the semicolons inside of quotes should be ignored, and only the *normal* semicolons should be replaced with `";"`

I used the batch interpreter itself to solve this for me.

- First I have to make the string *safe*, escaping all special characters.
- Then all `;` are replaced with `^;^;`
- and then the trick begins with the line
  `set var=%var:"=""%"` (The missing quote is the key!).
  This expands in a way such that all escaped characters will lose their escape caret:
  `var=foo & bar;;baz<>gak;;"semi^;^;colons^;^;^&embedded";;foo again!;;`...
  *But only outside of the quotes*, so now there is a difference between semicolons outside of quotes `;;` and inside `^;^;`.
  Thats the key.

Comment: My test string I currently use is `foo bar;baz gak;"semi;colons;embedded";foo again;throw (in) some (parentheses);"unmatched ;-)";(too` but your longer solution trips over the `"unmatched ;-)"`. +1 for the shorter approach, though; now that I see it it's obvious, alas it didn't come to me.

Comment: Works great for me - my path is long, but simple (nothing in paths but '\'). `%~a` strips the quotes from each item, I see. I don't understand what `"%path:;=";"%"` does - are you able to explain this? (Completely happy that this works for me though, thanks!)

Comment: `"%path:;=";"%"` changes `c:\bin;c:\another bin` into `"c:\bin";"c:\another bin"`. Can you see what's going on here?

Comment: @bobbogo: I get it now, thanks. The ; -> ";" inside quotes was confusing me. I also didn't realise that the shell would interpret `("a";"b")` as separate strings (I thought this had to be `(A B)`).

Comment: @Joey: You got me, the quotes in the path are really hard to handle

Comment: jeb: My attempt at parsing it (simple FSA) currently has 35 commented lines ;-) (and still fails, sadly). So I'm not much further than you are on that count ;-)

Comment: @joey: Are embedded `"` and `;` valid in _$PATH_?

Comment: @bobbogo: Yes of course, I name all my directories "Progam;and;Files" :-) @Joey: Currently my solution needs 20 lines, but what the hell is FSA? (Fussballverband Sachsen-Anhalt ?)

Comment: Finite State Automaton ;-). I'm not into football (actually, the only sport I'm following currently is Starcraft 2). @bobbogo: Since `;` is a valid character for file and directory names it has to be quoted in `PATH`. So yes, it can happen (it's rare, though). And I don't particularly like solutions that can break, especially if I'm not in control of their use. You see, batch files are more of an arcane art and many people here just tend to copy solutions verbatim and try cobbling something together without understanding what they're doing. So I usually strive for solutions without surprises

Comment: @Joey: Ok, I need 30 lines, but without FSA or parsing only with simple replace operations, I hope it is arcane enough :-)

Comment: Yikes, that's evil. Well, I worked on it on a character-by-character basis but I still can't handle quoting. Didn't touch it in a few hours, though ;-)

Comment: @Joey: @jeb: Ah, OK. I didn't know ntfs was good (?) enough to support `;` in filenames. You learn something new every day.

Comment: @bobbogo: The only invalid characters in NTFS file names are `/` and `\0`. The userland Windows API restricts that a little further, but that includes only characters used for the shell (`<>&|*?"\`).

Comment: @Joey: Wow, you are right. Cygwin can deal fine with `1<`, `1"`, `1:`, though cmd and the explorer struggle to display the filename.

Comment: @bobbogo: Historicaly, Cygwin had its own file name handling emulation layer, though, as it sat directly above Win32. SUA uses the kernel-level API though (since it's an environment subsystem) and therefore has direct access.

Comment: "The simple way" doesn't seem to work, but heck, the gist of your answer does and that's fantastic.

Answer (score 81):

A simple one liner to prettying printing the `PATH` environment variable:

```
ECHO.%PATH:;= & ECHO.%
```

If your `PATH` was equal to `A;B;C` the above string substitution will change this to `ECHO.A & ECHO.B & ECHO.C` and execute it all in one go. The full stop prevents the "ECHO is on" messages from appearing.

Comment: Works great for me in `cmd` but fails in PowerShell

Comment: It's so beautiful 

Answer (score 15):

An update to Stephan Quan's very clever one-liner solution: The problem I encountered was that a trailing semi-colon - (and maybe two successive semi-colons, i.e. empty path element) would cause the message "ECHO is on" to appear. I solved this by inserting a period immediately after the second ECHO statement (which is the syntax to suppress ECHO is on/off messages). However, it will result in an extra empty line:

```
ECHO %PATH:;= & ECHO.%
```

Comment: it's [cmd.exe variable edit/replace syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html): %variable:StrToFind=NewStr%, so that given `PATH=A;B` and the former echo command gets expanded to `ECHO A & ECHO.B`. The `ECHO.` replacement is needed for empty PATH elements.

Answer (score 12):

I have minor improvements to jeb's clever "always" solution. Currently jeb's solution has the following issues:

1. If the leading path is enclosed in quotes, then the first output
   starts with ""
2. If the trailing path is enclosed in quotes, then the last output
   ends with ""
3. If any path contains harmless but non-functional consecutive "",
   then the output preserves the ""
4. If var contains consecutive ;; delimiters then outputs **ECHO is off**

This solution fixes the minor issues, plus it uses 2 fewer substitutions. Also I eliminated the unnecessary repeated enabling/disabling delayed expansion within the loop. *(Edit on 2011-10-30 simplified the ENDLOCAL logic)*

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "var=%var:"=""%"
set "var=%var:^=^^%"
set "var=%var:&=^&%"
set "var=%var:|=^|%"
set "var=%var:<=^<%"
set "var=%var:>=^>%"
set "var=%var:;=^;^;%"
set var=%var:""="%
set "var=%var:"=""Q%"
set "var=%var:;;="S"S%"
set "var=%var:^;^;=;%"
set "var=%var:""="%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=!var:"Q=!"
for %%a in ("!var:"S"S=";"!") do (
  if "!!"=="" endlocal
  if %%a neq "" echo %%~a
)
```

If you want to see a blank line for each empty path resulting from consecutive ;; delimiters, then the last line of the FOR loop can simply read `echo(%%~a` instead.

Or perhaps it would be more obvious to display empty paths as "" using:
`if %%a=="" (echo "") else echo %%~a`

The various empty path fixes work for jeb's simple solution as well.

### UPDATE: Here is a simple one-liner using JREPL.BAT

You can use my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) to achieve a simple, very robust solution. JREPL.BAT is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jrepl "([^;\q]+|\q.*?(\q|$))+" $0 /x /jmatch /s path
```

Answer (score 4):

[Stephen Quan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353778/673991) is shorter and better, but here's a Python solution:

```
python -c "import os; print(os.environ['PATH'].replace(';', '\n'));"
```

Turning `;` semicolons into `\n` newlines.

Answer (score 3):

This works in cmd window using Git Bash on Windows:

`echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}`

You can also make a handy alias in your `.bash_profile`:

`alias showpath='echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}'`

Answer (score 2):

@ROMANIA_engineer proposed a PowerShell solution in a comment. Since the question asks for a command that works in the CMD shell, here is a way to use that elegant code from the OP's desired environment:

`powershell -Command ($env:Path).split(';')`

To make it still more readable, you can add sorting:

`powershell -Command ($env:Path).split(';') | sort`

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34920014/704808

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but FWIW; I always run into wanting this for some reason or another. Some time ago, I wrote myself a script to do this. I put a little polish on it and posted it on my blog.

Feel free to use it.

It's called epath, and the file is at inzi.com. It's compiled as an EXE for easy use (using vbsedit): [here](http://inzi.com/2013/09/epath-exe-view-path-broken-out-in-lines-from-the-command-prompt/)

You can download the exe there. Here's the source code to the script if you want it as a vbs script.

```
    scriptname = Wscript.ScriptName 'objFSO.GetFileName(WScript.FullName)

    Function BubbleSort(arrData,strSort)
    'borrowed from here: http://vbscripter.blogspot.com/2008/03/q-how-do-i-sort-data-in-array.html

    'Input: arrData = Array of data.  Text or numbers.
    'Input: strSort = Sort direction (ASC or ascending or DESC for descending)
    'Output: Array
    'Notes: Text comparison is CASE SENSITIVE
    '        strSort is checked for a match to ASC or DESC or else it defaults to Asc


        strSort = Trim(UCase(strSort))
        If Not strSort = "ASC" And Not strSort = "DESC" Then
            strSort = "ASC"
        End If 

        For i = LBound(arrData) to UBound(arrData)
          For j = LBound(arrData) to UBound(arrData)
            If j <> UBound(arrData) Then
                If strSort = "ASC" Then
                  If UCase(arrData(j)) > UCase(arrData(j + 1)) Then
                     TempValue = arrData(j + 1)
                     arrData(j + 1) = arrData(j)
                     arrData(j) = TempValue
                  End If
                End If

                If strSort = "DESC" Then
                    If UCase(arrData(j)) < UCase(arrData(j + 1)) Then
                        TempValue = arrData(j + 1)
                        arrData(j + 1) = arrData(j)
                        arrData(j) = TempValue
                     End If        
                End If 
            End If
          Next
        Next

        BubbleSort = arrData

    End Function

    If Wscript.Arguments.Count>0 Then

        Set args = Wscript.Arguments

        bInLines = False
        bInAlphabetical = False
        bReverseSort = False
        bShowHelp = False

        For Each arg In args
            Select Case arg
                Case "-l"
                    bInLines = True
                Case "-a"
                    bInAlphabetical = True
                Case "-r"
                    bReverseSort = True
                Case Else
                    bShowHelp=True
            End Select  

        Next

        If bInLines = False Then
            bShowHelp=True
        End if

        If bShowHelp Then

                    sTxt = sTxt + "" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt +  scriptname  & " Displays the system path in optionally friendly formats." & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt +  "ePath is helpful when viewing the system path and easily identifying folders therein." & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt + "" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt + "EPATH [-l] [-a] [-r]" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt + "" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt + "Switches:" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt + vbTab + "[-l]" + vbtab + "Show the path broken out in lines" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt + vbtab + "[-a]" + vbTab + "Sort the path broken out in lines sorted alphabetically" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt + vbtab + "[-r]" + vbTab + "Reverse the alphabetic sort [asc default] (ignored without -a)" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt + "" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt + vbTab + "Examples:" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt +  vbTab + vbTab + scriptname  & vbTab & "(Show %PATH% normally)" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt +  vbTab + vbTab + scriptname  & " -l" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt +  vbTab + vbTab + scriptname  & " -l -a" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt +  vbTab + vbTab + scriptname  & " -l -a -r" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt +  vbTab + vbTab + scriptname  & " -? Display help (what you are seeing now)" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt + "" & vbCrLf
                    sTxt = sTxt + "More info or questions at http://inzi.com" & vbCrLf


                    Wscript.Echo sTxt

                    WScript.Quit

        Else
            Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
            sPath = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%PATH%" )
            thePath = Split(sPath,";")

            If bInAlphabetical Then
                If bReverseSort Then
                    sDirection = "DESC"
                End If

                thePath = BubbleSort(thePath, sDirection)
            End if


            For Each item In thePath
                WScript.Echo item
            Next
            Set wshShell = Nothing
        End if
    Else
        'Nothing, echo the path.

        Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
        WScript.Echo wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%PATH%" )
        Set wshShell = Nothing

    End If
```

Comment: @Marble68 epath.exe is exactly what I was looking for -- thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a well commented script that parses a semicolon-separated list of items, regarding optional quotation of each item and allowing even items with semicolons in them (when quoted). Since it utilises a `goto` loop it might not be the fastest approach though, but it should be safe against special characters:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define semicolon-separated list here (sample taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168):
set "BUFFER=foo & bar;baz<>gak;"semi;colons;^&embedded";foo again!;throw (in) some (parentheses);"unmatched ;-)";(too"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo BUFFER: !BUFFER!
echo/
endlocal

rem // Initialise items counter and clear (pseudo-)array variable:
set /A "IDX=0" & for /F "delims==" %%V in ('set $ITEM[ 2^> nul') do set "%%V="
rem // Utilise a `goto` loop to retrieve all items:
:PARSE_LOOP
rem // Check for availability of further items:
if defined BUFFER (
    rem // Increment items counter:
    set /A "IDX+=1"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Put current items counter into a `for` meta-variable:
    for %%I in (!IDX!) do (
        rem // Check whether current item begins with `"`, hence it is quoted:
        if "!BUFFER:~,1!" == ""^" (
            rem /* This point is reached when current item is quoted, hence
            rem    remove the opening `"` and split off everything past the
            rem    next one (that is the closing `"`) from the items buffer: */
            for /F tokens^=1*^ delims^=^"^ eol^=^" %%A in (";!BUFFER:~1!") do (
                endlocal
                rem // Store current item into array in unquoted manner:
                set "$ITEM[%%I]=%%A" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                for /F "delims=" %%C in ("$ITEM[%%I]=!$ITEM[%%I]:~1!") do (
                    endlocal & set "%%C" & if not defined $ITEM[%%I] set /A "IDX-=1"
                )
                rem /* Transfer remaining items beyond `endlocal` barrier;
                rem    note that a delimiters-only line still causes `for /F`
                rem    to iterate when there is just `tokens=*`: */
                for /F "tokens=* delims=;" %%D in (";%%B") do set "BUFFER=%%D"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        ) else (
            rem /* This point is reached when current item is not quoted,
            rem    hence split items string at next semicolon `;`: */
            for /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%A in ("!BUFFER!") do (
                endlocal
                rem // Store current (unquoted) item into array:
                set "$ITEM[%%I]=%%A"
                rem // Transfer remaining items beyond `endlocal` barrier:
                set "BUFFER=%%B"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
    )
    endlocal
    rem // Loop back to retrieve next item:
    goto :PARSE_LOOP
)
rem // Return all retrieved items:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%I in (1,1,%IDX%) do echo ITEM %%I: !$ITEM[%%I]!
endlocal

echo/
echo INFO:   %IDX% items
echo ERROR:  %ErrorLevel%

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Nice solution, I like the idea to detect only quotes and then take all to the next quote or semicolon

Answer (score 1):

#### Original Version

This is an approach that only performs several character substitutions, which can properly handle a semicolon-separated list of optionally quoted items, which, when quoted, may even contain semicolons on their own. Empty list items are also dealt with correctly. The key to success is to become able to distinguish between semicolons within quotes (which are part of a list item) and those not (which constitute the separators):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define semicolon-separated list here (sample taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168):
set "BUFFER=foo & bar;baz<>gak;"semi;colons;^&embedded";foo again!;throw (in) some (parentheses);"unmatched ;-)";(too"
rem set "BUFFER="caret ^^";"bang !";"caret ^^ bang !""

set BUFFER & echo/

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Replace `^` by `^@` to avoid sequences of `^`:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^=^@!"

rem // Escape special characters `^`, `&`, `<`, `>`, `|`:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^=^^!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:&=^&!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:<=^<!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:>=^>!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:|=^|!"

rem // Escape `;`:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:;=^;!"

rem // Expand immediately, so escaping is processed for unquoted portions:
endlocal & set ^"BUFFER=%BUFFER%^"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Escape `^`, `&`, `<`, `>`, `|`, hence quoted portions become double-escaped:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^=^^!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:&=^&!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:<=^<!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:>=^>!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:|=^|!"

rem /* Replace `^^^` by `^` in order to resolve double-escaping;
rem    at this point, quoted `;` are represented by the sequence `^^;`: */
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^^^=^!"

rem // Escape `"`, so everything appears unquoted then:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:"=^^"!"

rem /* Expand immediately, so escaping is again processed;
rem    at this point, originally quoted `;` are represented by `^;`: */
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^=^^^!"
set ^"BUFFER=%BUFFER:!=^^!%^" !

rem // Remove all `"` from string:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:"=!^"

rem // Enclose whole string in `""` and replace each `;` by `";"`:
set ^"BUFFER="!BUFFER:;=";"!"^"

rem // Replace `^";"` (which are originally quoted `;`) by `;`:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^";"=;!"

rem // Finally revert initial replacement of `^` by `^@`:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^@=^!"

set BUFFER & echo/

rem // Eventually return the list items:
for %%I in (!BUFFER!) do (
    if "!!"=="" endlocal & rem // (technique taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7940444)
    echo(%%~I
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

#### Improved Version

Here is an improved approach that performs less substitutions:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define semicolon-separated list here:
set "BUFFER="caret ^^";"bang !";"caret ^^; ^& bang !";caret ^;bang !;caret ^@ & bang !"

set BUFFER & echo/

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Replace `^` by `^@` to avoid sequences of `^`:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^=^@!"

rem // Double-escape special characters `^`, `&`, `<`, `>`, `|`:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^=^^^^!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:&=^^^&!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:<=^^^<!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:>=^^^>!"
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:|=^^^|!"

rem // Replace `;` by `^^;`:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:;=^^;!"

rem // Expand immediately, so escaping is processed for unquoted portions:
endlocal & set ^"BUFFER=%BUFFER%^"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem /* Replace `^^^` by `^` in order to resolve double-escaping; at this point,
rem    quoted `;` are represented by the sequence `^^;`, unquoted ones by `^;`: */
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^^^=^!"

rem // Escape `"`, so everything appears unquoted then:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:"=^^"!"

rem /* Expand immediately, so escaping is again processed;
rem    at this point, originally quoted `;` are represented by `^;`: */
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^=^^^!"
set ^"BUFFER=%BUFFER:!=^^!%^" !

rem // Remove all `"` from string:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:"=!^"

rem // Enclose whole string in `""` and replace each `;` by `";"`:
set ^"BUFFER="!BUFFER:;=";"!"^"

rem // Replace `^";"` (which are originally quoted `;`) by `;`:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^";"=;!"

rem // Finally revert initial replacement of `^` by `^@`:
set "BUFFER=!BUFFER:^@=^!"

set BUFFER & echo/

rem // Eventually return the list items:
for %%I in (!BUFFER!) do (if "!!"=="" endlocal) & echo(%%~I

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Also nice, but I can't see a big difference to dbenham's answer (or my own)? But it's better annotated :-)

Comment: Thanks, @jeb! Well, there is not a big difference, I just started from scratch and this is what I came up with; opposed to your approach, delayed expansion is enabled during the substitutions, which is probably the major difference; there are perhaps a little simpler substitutions, but there are more… anyway, there is still room for improvement, I guess…

Comment: Good point, there was a reason I used disabled delayed expansion, your version fails entirely with `set "BUFFER="caret ^^";"bang !";"caret ^^ bang !"`. The challange begins :-)

Comment: I knew you will find a destructive sample string… ;-) (are the unbalanced quotes intentional?) it works when I use the commented out (`::`) alternative way of immediate expansion… :-D still working on it…

Comment: The unbalanced quotes weren't intentional, only by accident. I'm waiting for your next try

Comment: Alright, @jeb, so it seems that I have to temporarily disable delayed expansion during the first immediate expansion action to avoid problems with quoted and unquoted `!`-marks; now it should work (I hope). Anyway, I eventually posted a more compact approach with less substitutions; up to now I could not find any test strings it fails with…

Answer (score 1):

Returning to this, in the case you have `node.js` and inspired by [Bob Stein answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30001363/185756) for `python` one-liner.

```
node -e "console.log(process.env.path.replace(/;/g,'\n'))"
```

Or longer way:

```
node -e "console.log(process.env.path.split(';').join('\n'))"
```

I needed to find lines where `git` is installed so:

```
node -e "console.log(process.env.path.split(';').filter(str=>str.match(/git/i)).join('\n'))"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another implementation enough compact and functional.

https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Scripts/Tools/std/echo_path_var.bat

**echo_path_var.bat**:

```
@echo off

rem USAGE:
rem   echo_path_var.bat <VAR> [<PREFIX> [<SUFFIX>]]

rem <VAR>: VALUE1;VALUE2;...;VALUEN

setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "__?VAR__=%~1"
if not defined __?PREFIX__ set "__?PREFIX__=%~2"
if not defined __?SUFFIX__ set "__?SUFFIX__=%~3"

if not defined __?VAR__ exit /b 255
if not defined %__?VAR__% exit /b 1

rem Escape specific separator characters by sequence of `$NN` characters:
rem  1. `?` and `*` - globbing characters in the `for %%i in (...)` expression
rem  2. `,`, ` `    - separator characters in the `for %%i in (...)` expression
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!%__?VAR__%:$=$00!") do ( endlocal & set "%__?VAR__%=%%i" )
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!%__?VAR__%:^*=$01!") do ( endlocal & set "%__?VAR__%=%%i" )
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!%__?VAR__%:^?=$02!") do ( endlocal & set "%__?VAR__%=%%i" )
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!%__?VAR__%: =$03!") do ( endlocal & set "%__?VAR__%=%%i" )
rem escape tabulation character
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!%__?VAR__%:  =$04!") do ( endlocal & set "%__?VAR__%=%%i" )
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!%__?VAR__%:,=$05!") do ( endlocal & set "%__?VAR__%=%%i" )

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!%__?VAR__%!") do (
  endlocal
  for %%j in (%%i) do (
    set "__?LINE__=%%j"
    rem unescape
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!__?LINE__:$01=^*!") do ( endlocal & set "__?LINE__=%%i" )
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!__?LINE__:$02=^?!") do ( endlocal & set "__?LINE__=%%i" )
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!__?LINE__:$03= !") do ( endlocal & set "__?LINE__=%%i" )
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!__?LINE__:$04=   !") do ( endlocal & set "__?LINE__=%%i" )
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!__?LINE__:$05=,!") do ( endlocal & set "__?LINE__=%%i" )
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!__?LINE__:$00=$!") do ( endlocal & set "__?LINE__=%%i" )
    rem trim leading white spaces
    rem setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims= " %%i in ("!__?LINE__!") do ( endlocal & set "__?LINE__=%%i" )
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!__?PREFIX__!!__?LINE__!!__?SUFFIX__!") do ( endlocal & echo.%%i)
  )
)

exit /b 0
```

**echo_var.bat**:

```
@echo off

rem USAGE:
rem   echo_var.bat <VAR> [<PREFIX> [<SUFFIX>]]

setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "__?VAR__=%~1"
if not defined __?PREFIX__ set "__?PREFIX__=%~2"
if not defined __?SUFFIX__ set "__?SUFFIX__=%~3"

if not defined __?VAR__ exit /b 255
if not defined %__?VAR__% exit /b 1

rem safe echo
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION & for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("!__?PREFIX__!!%__?VAR__%!!__?SUFFIX__!") do ( endlocal & echo.%%i)
exit /b 0
```

**Warning**:

The `eol=`  actually is not empty and contains the `04` code character.

**Examples**:

1.

```
>
echo_path_var.bat PATH ` `
```

2. To use with double quotes:

```
>
set __?PREFIX__=^"
set __?SUFFIX__=^"
echo_path_var.bat PATH
```

3. 

```
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set AAA=123
rem with tabulation character
set BBB="?a/b/%%c%%!" ^;     "!d! ^; e ; f" ; ; ; !AAA! ^^; g,g ;;; h h

call "%%~dp0echo_var.bat" BBB ` `
call "%%~dp0echo_path_var.bat" BBB ` `
```

```
`"?a/b/%c%!" ;   "!d! ^; e ; f" ; ; ; !AAA! ^; g,g ;;; h h`
`"?a/b/%c%!" `
`        "!d! ^; e ; f" `
` `
` `
` !AAA! ^`
` g,g `
` h h`
```

4. With globbing:

```
set "A=c:\windows\*.exe"
call "%%~dp0echo_var.bat A"
call "%%~dp0echo_path_var.bat A"
```

```
c:\windows\*.exe
c:\windows\bfsvc.exe
c:\windows\explorer.exe
c:\windows\fveupdate.exe
c:\windows\GSetup.exe
c:\windows\HelpPane.exe
c:\windows\hh.exe
c:\windows\notepad.exe
c:\windows\pfm.exe
c:\windows\ptsysexec.exe
c:\windows\pttestcmd.exe
c:\windows\py.exe
c:\windows\pyw.exe
c:\windows\regedit.exe
c:\windows\splwow64.exe
c:\windows\twunk_16.exe
c:\windows\twunk_32.exe
c:\windows\winhlp32.exe
c:\windows\write.exe
```

```
set "A=c:\windows\??.exe"
call "%%~dp0echo_var.bat A"
call "%%~dp0echo_path_var.bat A"
```

```
c:\windows\??.exe
c:\windows\hh.exe
c:\windows\py.exe
```

**Pros**:

- Use the `for %%i in (...)` statement to parse a path list value to parse `VALUE;VALUE` the same way as `"VALUE";"VALUE"`.
- Prints spaces and tabulation characters as is.
- Ignores sequence of `;` (ex: `;;;`) and treats it a single character.
- Can be used with globbing by default (in windows a path should not contain `*` and `?` characters).

**Cons**:

- Because `!VAR:*=...!` expression does not work as expected, and `*`, `?` are globbing characters, then a string with `*` and `?` characters must be in preformatted form: `1 * 2 ? 3` -> `1 ^* 2 ^? 3`
- Needs to separately trim leading and trailing white space characters.

Answer (score 0):

This script will parse the current windows path into at txt file using JREPL.bat.
It was inspired by the above post by dbenham.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:::: THIS SCRIPT WILL PARSE THE CURRENT WINDOWS PATH INTO AT TXT FILE ::::
:::: EACH FOLDER FOUND IN PATH WILL BE ON A SEPARATE LINE ::::

:::: SCRIPT INSTRUCTIONS ::::
:: PLACE JREPL.bat IN C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 FOLDER OR CUSTOM LOCATION OF YOUR CHOOSING ::
:: IF PLACED IN CUSTOM FOLDER YOU MUST LINK IT TO WINDOWS PATH ::
:: YOU CAN ACCESS WINDOWS PATH BY RUNNING THE BELOW COMMAND IN CMD.EXE ::
:: Rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables ::
:: DOWNLOAD JREPL.bat https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044 ::

:: SET WORKING DIRECTORY ::
CD /D "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32"

:: UNCOMMENT LINE BELOW AND SET YOUR JREPL.bat SAVED FOLDER PATH IF YOU HAVE A BACKUP COPY ::
:: SET JOUT=<FOLDER PATH>

:: SET OUTPUT FILE ::
    SET FOUT=%USERPROFILE%\DESKTOP\PARSE.TXT

:: SET FILE TO SEARCH FOR ::
:: THIS SEARCHES FOR JREPL.BAT IN THE CURRENT WORKING DIR ::
    SET I=JREPL.BAT

:: SET CONTROL FILE TO CHECK AGAINST ::
:: THIS IS FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES AND SHOULD NOT BE CHANGED OTHERWISE ::
    SET J=JREPL.BAT

:::: START SCRIPT ::::
    SET RESULT=
    FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('DIR /B /O:N ^| FINDSTR /S /I "%I%" %TMP_RESULT_FILE%') DO (
    SET RESULT=%%A
    )

IF /I !RESULT! EQU %J% (
ECHO !RESULT! ^^!^^!EXISTS^^!^^!
    TIMEOUT 3 >NUL
    CALL :FOUND
    GOTO END
) ELSE (
    GOTO NOTFOUND
)
    GOTO ERROR

:FOUND
    FOR %%G IN (%I%) DO (
    %%G "([^;\Q]+|\Q.*?(\Q|$))+" $0 /X /JMATCH /S PATH>>%FOUT%
    CLS && ECHO.
ECHO %I% ^^!^^!EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY^^!^^!
    TIMEOUT /T 3 >NUL
    EXPLORER "%FOUT%"
    GOTO END
( ELSE )
    GOTO ERROR
)

:NOTFOUND
    ECHO %I% ^^!^^!NOT FOUND^^!^^!
    TIMEOUT 3 >NUL
    CLS && ECHO.
:: UNCOMMENT THE LINES BELOW TO OPEN JREPL.BAT SAVE FOLDER IF AVAILABLE ::
    :: ECHO ^^!^^!OPENING^^!^^! %I%'S SAVED FOLDER
  :: TIMEOUT 3 >NUL
    :: EXPLORER "%JOUT%"
  GOTO END
    ( ELSE )
    GOTO ERROR
    )

:ERROR
    CLS && ECHO.
    ECHO ^^!^^!ERROR RUNNING^^!^^! %I%
    TIMEOUT 3 >NUL
    CLS && ECHO.
    ECHO ^^!^^!PLEASE FIX SCRIPT^^!^^! ::::::::::::::::::
    TIMEOUT 3 >NUL

:END
    ENDLOCAL && EXIT /B
```