# Loop through CSV file with batch - Space issue

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a csv file like this

```
name,sex,age
venu,m,16
test,,22
```

**[EDIT]**
name could have comma also

```
"venu,gopal",m,16
```

I want to handle if sex is nothing and save it to another file.

I have a script like this

```
@Echo Off
For /F "usebackq tokens=1-3  delims=," %%a in (test.csv) Do (
   echo %%a, %%b, %%c >> test-new.csv
)
```

But for the third record, I am getting %%b as 22 which should be space. How to fix this?

**[EDIT2]**

I have tried as per that link. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am getting same issue. Please check it once.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

For /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=" %%x in (C:\somefile.csv) Do (

    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=%%x"   

    set "var=!var:"=""!"
    set "var=!var:^=^^!"
    set "var=!var:&=^&!"
    set "var=!var:|=^|!"
    set "var=!var:<=^<!"
    set "var=!var:>=^>!"
    set "var=!var:,=^,^,!"
    set var=!var:""="!
    set "var=!var:"=""Q!"
    set "var=!var:,,="S"S!"
    set "var=!var:^,^,=,!"
    set "var=!var:""="!"
    set "var=!var:"Q=!"


    For /F "tokens=1-3  delims=," %%a in ("!var:"S"S=","!") Do (
      endlocal
      echo %%~a, %%~b, %%~c
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
      pause
    )

    endlocal

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, as multiple delims will be condensed to a single delim.

So you need to replace them before to a *unique* delim sequence.

```
@Echo Off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "usebackq tokens=1-3  delims=" %%a in (test.csv) Do (
    set "line=%%a"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line="!line:,=","!""
    For /F "tokens=1-3  delims=," %%a in ("!line!") Do (
        echo %%~a, %%~b, %%~c 
    )
)
```

This enclose each column into quotes, and with the `%%~a` the quotes will be removed later

**EDIT: The solution for embedded commas**

In this case it's only a bit different than the solution for [how to split on ';' in CMD shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168/463115)

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

For /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=" %%x in (test.csv) Do (
    set "var=%%x"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=!var:^=^^!"
    set "var=!var:&=^&!"
    set "var=!var:|=^|!"
    set "var=!var:<=^<!"
    set "var=!var:>=^>!"
    set "var=!var:,=^,^,!"
    rem ** This is the key line, the missing quote is intention
    call set var=%%var:""="%%
    set "var=!var:"="Q!"
    set "var=!var:^,^,="C!"
    set "var=!var:,,=,!"
    set "var=!var:""="!"

    set "var="!var:,=","!""
    for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ("!var!") do (      
        endlocal
        set "col1=%%~a"
        set "col2=%%~b"
        set "col3=%%~c"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if defined col1 (
            set "col1=!col1:"C=,!"
            set "col1=!col1:"Q="!"
        )

        if defined col2 (
            set "col2=!col2:"C=,!"
            set "col2=!col2:"Q="!"
        )

        if defined col3 (
            set "col3=!col3:"C=,!"
            set "col3=!col3:"Q="!"
        )
        echo a=!col1!, b=!col2!, c=!col3!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Comment: But its not working when there is a comma in the name.. how to fix it.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then you should show how your csv is formatted with names including commas (perhaps `"Smith, John",m,25`?)

Comment: yeah apologies for that.. could you please tell me how to fix this? I will modify my question

Comment: It's a bit ;-) more complicated, something similar is solved at [how to split on ';' in CMD shell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168/463115)

Comment: Please check my updated code. I have been struggling to find the solution. Please shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its is perfect. I have another small issue when there is a line break in text. shall I post another question..

Comment: I have posted another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714901/loop-through-csv-file-with-batch-line-break-issue

Please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

using a string editor like SSED, I have overcome this issue by creating a temp file where I have replaced ",," with ",-," twice, then regarding a "-" as having been an empty field in the original file...

```
 ssed "s/,,/,-,/ig;s/,,/,-,/ig" file1.csv > file1.tmp
```

Then the tokens are allocated correctly.  If you need to edit the temp file and then return to a CSV, then use...

```
 ssed "s/,-,/,,/ig;s/,-,/,,/ig" file1.tmp > file1.csv
```

This seems much simpler than doing in flight string replacements by token and having subroutines/etc.