# Need to parse %PATH% with FOR loop in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to make a FOR loop to do some operations with each path in %PATH% variable. But FOR sees %PATH% as one line and makes only one iteration for the whole variable. How can I parse every directory's path in %PATH%?

Comment: Use a semi-colon as your delimiter in your `FOR` loop?

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how many directories are in %PATH%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %G in ("%path:;=" "%") do @echo %G
```

From:

http://ss64.com/nt/path.html

Comment: This will not work if PATH contains some paths that are already quoted. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5471556/1012053 has an answer that will always work.