# windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell again

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, path, cmd

I just checked [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471556/pretty-print-windows-path-variable-how-to-split-on-in-cmd-shell) that seemed to be very helpful and worked fine on Windows XP. But using Windows 7 it does not work for some obscure reason.

The `PATH` variable looks like this

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
```

It obviously contains \ as well as semicolons I use to split in a batch that contains this FOR-loop:

```
   FOR /F "delims=;" %%A IN ("%PATH%") DO (
      echo %%A
   )
```

Executing does not cause any error but it provides just one (the first) token

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
```

I had no idea why FOR terminates and played around with several variations that have been suggested on the net but none did the job.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Christian

Comment: You cited a duplicate question that contains a great accepted answer with two solutions. jeb's first solution works in most situations, but can fail. His second solution always works. Yet you opted to try something else entirely. Read jeb's solution more carefully! He used FOR, not FOR /F.

Answer (score 24):

You could do it this way.

```
for %%A in ("%path:;=";"%") do (
    echo %%~A
)
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471556/))

The problem with the way you have it is that, using the `for /F` switch,  `%%A` only specifies the first token.  You would have to do `for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=;" %%A in ("%PATH%")` and read in `%%A` through `%%I` that way.

Comment: And the issue with the tokens=1-9 possibility, is that it can only get the first several (9) path entries, and we typically have more than that these days.  So your main answer (without the /F) is the best thing.

Comment: Just found this solution.  On Windows 10 take off the second percent sign to get:
for %T in ("%path:;=";"%") do (echo %~T)
I also turned off ECHO in the command line for added readability.

Answer (score 3):

Combining things learned on this and various other stackoverflow pages, the OP can be extended to:

**How to ensure the PATH variable has unique values?**

Which can be done this way, using array variables:

```
REM usage: call :make_path_unique VARNAME "%VARNAME%"
REM 1: splits VARNAME on ';' and builds an array of unique values (case insensitive)
REM 2: glues the array back into a single variable
REM 3: set the VARNAME to this newly unique-ified collection.
REM
REM From: various StackOverflow pages:
REM     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471556/pretty-print-windows-path-variable-how-to-split-on-in-cmd-shell
REM     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262287/make-an-environment-variable-survive-endlocal
REM     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879105/windows-path-variable-how-to-split-on-in-cmd-shell-again
REM
:make_path_unique
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set VNAME=%~1
  set VPATH=%~2
  set I=0
  for %%A in ("%VPATH:;=";"%") do (
    set FOUND=NO
    for /L %%B in (1,1,!I!) do (
        if /I "%%~A"=="!L[%%B]!" set FOUND=YES
    )
    if NO==!FOUND! (
        set /A I+=1
        set L[!I!]=%%~A
    )
  )
  set FINAL=!L[1]!
  for /L %%n in (2,1,!I!) do (
    set FINAL=!FINAL!;!L[%%n]!
    set L[%%n]=
  )
  for %%P in ("!FINAL!") do (
    endlocal
    set %VNAME%=%%~P
  )
  exit /b 0
```

Summary of steps:

1. for loop splitting PATH at ';' and properly managing quotes

   1. for loop looking at all previously stored paths
   2. only extend the array if this is a new path to be added
2. glue the array pack together, clearing the array variable as we go
3. replace the path and clear the temporary variables
4. return from function with no errors.

invoked, of course, with:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%MY_PATH_ADDITIONS%
call :make_path_unique PATH "%PATH%"
```

Comment: Thanks, @LotPings, for the edit. caseless compare is better, and setlocal/endlocal is cleaner.