# How to make a new line in a text file at every instance of character X - Windows 7?

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, batch-file

I have a text file filled with characters:

```
ABCABCABCABC
```

...and with a script (Batch, VBS, Powershell, anything simple for Windows really) am trying to automatically add a new line for every instance of a certain character, in this case the letter A, so the output would then appear as such:

```
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
```

How can this be accomplished with any of the scripting tools I mentioned above?

Much appreciated, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6):

Powershell:

```
(get-content c:\somedir\inputfile.txt) -replace 'A',"`nA" | set-content c:\somedir\outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Updated code to show example use for file processing.  For very large files you may need to adjust that to use -readcount and a foreach-object loop to conserve memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use SED  `GOOGLE GNUSED`

```
sed s/A/\nA/g <yourfile >resultfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++

This is just a find and replace if you have `notepad++` installed  on your computer
(http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.3.1.html)

Open your text file, press <kbd>Ctrl H</kbd> to get Find & Replace

Select Search Mode as  `Extended`  or `Regular expression`

Find `A`

Replace `\nA`

Answer (score 0):

Windows batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo contents of oldfile.txt:
type oldfile.txt
echo;

del newfile.txt
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("oldfile.txt") do (
    set "str=%%I" && set "str=!str:A=,A!"
    for %%x in (!str!) do (>>"newfile.txt" echo %%x)
)

echo contents of newfile.txt:
type newfile.txt
```

Example output:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>test.bat
contents of oldfile.txt:
ABCABCABCABCABC

contents of newfile.txt:
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
```

Here's more info on [splitting a string in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15535761/1683264).

Answer (score 0):

JScript:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var read = fso.OpenTextFile("oldfile.txt", 1, 2);
var write = fso.CreateTextFile("newfile.txt", true);
var str = read.ReadAll();
write.Write(str.replace(/A/g,'\nA').replace(/^\n/m,''));
read.Close(); write.Close();
```

The second `.replace` removes the first new line if it occurs as the first character of the text.  Save this script with a `.js` extension and execute it with `cscript filename.js`.