# batch file reg query with logical operators (NOT)

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, registry, logical-operators

I am trying to write a reg query batch file that looks for key data that does NOT contain something. Currently, this code searches for a key `Dependent Files` (REG_MULTI_SZ) and will write the output to a file. I need it to ignore any data within `Dependent Files` containing "**.GPD*".

How do I incorporate logical operators into a simple REG QUERY?

```
@echo off
set file=c:\Temp\regcomplist.txt
for /f "Tokens=*" %%g in (%file%) do (
    echo %%g>> c:\Temp\regquery.txt
    REG QUERY "\\%%g\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows x64\Drivers\Version-3\Lexmark Universal v2 XL" /v "Dependent Files">> c:\Temp\regquery.txt
    echo.>> c:\Temp\regquery.txt
    echo.>> c:\Temp\regquery.txt
)
```

Comment: Pipe your `reg query` command into `find /i /v ".GPD"` or `find /i /v "**.GPD*"` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: That's useful, but how do I find where Dependent Values does NOT have *GPD*

Comment: DOH... thet's what the /v is ::FACEPALM::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch code with using the command as suggested by [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo) is:

```
@echo off
set "ListFile=C:\Temp\regcomplist.txt"
set "ResultsFile=C:\Temp\regquery.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%g in (%ListFile%) do (
    echo %%g>>%ResultsFile%
    %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "\\%%g\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows x64\Drivers\Version-3\Lexmark Universal v2 XL" /v "Dependent Files" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /i /v "**.GPD*">>%ResultsFile%
    echo.>>%ResultsFile%
    echo.>>%ResultsFile%
)
```

---

After adding information that registry value `Dependent Files` is of type `REG_MULTI_SZ`, I went to a computer having a printer installed (my one has not) and exported the registry key of this printer with **regedit** to a .reg file. Next I imported this registry file into registry of my computer and executed once `reg query` for this key to see how the multiline value is written to console by **reg**.

Then I could develop the commented batch file below.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Printer=Lexmark Universal v2 XL"
set "ListFile=C:\Temp\regcomplist.txt"
set "ResultsFile=C:\Temp\regquery.txt"
if exist "%ResultsFile%" del "%ResultsFile%"

rem Run the procedure GetPrinterFiles on each computer of list file.
for /f "delims=" %%g in (%ListFile%) do (
    echo %%g>>%ResultsFile%
    call :GetPrinterFiles "%%g"
    echo.>>%ResultsFile%
    echo.>>%ResultsFile%
)
endlocal
rem Exit this batch file.
goto :EOF

rem Get multiline string with the file names from registry and parse that
rem string with procedure GetFileNames if the printer is installed at all.

:GetPrinterFiles
for /F "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "\\%~1\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows x64\Drivers\Version-3\%Printer%" /v "Dependent Files" 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%A"== "REG_MULTI_SZ" (
        call :GetFileNames "%%B"
        goto :EOF
    )
)
rem Document in results file that printer is not installed on this computer.
echo Error: %Printer% not installed.>>%ResultsFile%

rem Exit procedure GetPrinterFiles and return to main loop above.
goto :EOF

rem The file names are passed from procedure GetPrinterFiles in a long string
rem with \0 as separator between the file names. This long string is split
rem into individual file names by the FOR loop below. Each file name is
rem assigned to an environment variable. A case-sensitive comparison is
rem made between value of this variable having all ".GPD" case-insensitive
rem removed with unmodified value of this variable. If modified variable
rem value is equal unmodified variable value, ".GPD" is not present in any
rem case in file name resulting in writing the file name into the results
rem file. Otherwise this file containing ".GPD" in any case is ignored.

:GetFileNames
set "FilesList=%~1"
for %%F in ("%FilesList:\0=","%") do (
    set "FileName=%%~F"
    if "!FileName:.GPD=!" == "!FileName!" (
        echo !FileName!>>%ResultsFile%
    )
)
rem Exit procedure GetFileNames and return to GetPrinterFiles procedure above.
goto :EOF
```

Thanks goes to [rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683264/rojo) for his answer on [separating variable with a symbol into different parts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15535761/3074564) showing me how to process the long string with all the file names separated by `\0` by **reg** on output.

Comment: This outputs Asian characters 慭档湩湥浡൥ഊഊ伊䑃㝔㌰㠲㌴ഷഊ etc.  Any ideas?

Comment: Beautiful! Would it be possible to ONLY output devices missing the dependent files WITH Lexmark Universal V XL?  I just need a list of machines with corrupted drivers, nothing else.  Your answer is epic though, thank you very much!

Comment: It would be of course possible to check which files are missing in __C:\Windows\Sysnative\spool\drivers\x64__ and its subdirectories and then write into the results file only the computers with 1 or more missing files and which files are missing.