# Proper usage of EnableDelayedExpansion in ASCII Converting Batch script

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, ascii

**Primary Question:**

How should the posted batch script, `combined.bat`, be changed so that I can have correct output for both `OUTPUT_A` and `OUTPUT_B` at the same runtime? (Knowledge of EnableDelayedExpansion usage/scope is required to provide a correct solution)

**Context:**

I combined batch scripts from the two following links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15535761/7889588

https://helloacm.com/the-chr-function-implementation-in-windows-pure-batch-script/

and created the following batch script *(let me refer to this as `combined.bat`)*:

`combined.bat` is meant to be an ASCII Dec to ASCII Char converter.

```
@echo off
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: define characters from 32 to 126
set alphabet= !"#$%%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"

set testVar=64_65_66_67_68_69_70_64
echo INPUT = %testVar%
echo.

set resultA=

call :CHR 64
set resultA=%resultA%%char%
call :CHR 65
set resultA=%resultA%%char%
call :CHR 66
set resultA=%resultA%%char%
call :CHR 67
set resultA=%resultA%%char%
call :CHR 68
set resultA=%resultA%%char%
call :CHR 69
set resultA=%resultA%%char%
call :CHR 70
set resultA=%resultA%%char%
call :CHR 64
set resultA=%resultA%%char%
echo OUTPUT_A = %resultA%
echo.

set char=randomValueJustToInitFill
call :split "%testVar%" "_" array

set resultB=
:: Loop through the resulting array
for /L %%I in (0, 1, %array.ubound%) do (
    call :CHR !array[%%I]!
    echo array[%%I] = !array[%%I]! = !char!
    set resultB=!resultB!!char!
)
echo OUTPUT_B = !resultB!
echo.
goto :EOF

:CHR
:: valid range should be from 32 to 126 inclusive
if "%1"=="" goto :EOF
if %1 LSS 32 goto :EOF
if %1 GTR 126 goto :EOF

:: call function
call :ASCII %1 chr

:: print result, using ^ to escape special characters 
:: such as <, > and |
REM echo.^%chr%
set char=^%chr%

:: end the script
goto :EOF

:: sub-routine
:ASCII
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        :: get the index
        set /a var=%1-32
        :: retrieve letter
        set character=!alphabet:~%var%,1!
    :: end the routine and return result as second parameter (out)
    endlocal & set %2=^%character%
@EXIT /B 0

:: split subroutine
:split <string_to_split> <split_delimiter> <array_to_populate>
:: populates <array_to_populate>
:: creates arrayname.length (number of elements in array)
:: creates arrayname.ubound (upper index of array)

set "_data=%~1"

:: replace delimiter with " " and enclose in quotes
set _data="!_data:%~2=" "!"

:: remove empty "" (comment this out if you need to keep empty elements)
set "_data=%_data:""=%"

:: initialize array.length=0, array.ubound=-1
set /a "%~3.length=0, %~3.ubound=-1"

for %%I in (%_data%) do (
    set "%~3[!%~3.length!]=%%~I"
    set /a "%~3.length+=1, %~3.ubound+=1"
)
@EXIT /B 0
@endlocal
```

when running `combined.bat`, it yields the following:

```
INPUT = 64_65_66_67_68_69_70_64

OUTPUT_A = Z[\]_`aZ

array[0] = 64 = Z
array[1] = 65 = [
array[2] = 66 = \
array[3] = 67 = ]
array[4] = 68 = _
array[5] = 69 = `
array[6] = 70 = a
array[7] = 64 = Z
OUTPUT_B = Z[\]_`aZ
```

`OUTPUT_A` and `OUTPUT_B` are both not correct. It is offset by `26`. I made an educated guess that this is caused by line `2` of `combined.bat`, `@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`.

So when I comment out line `2` by changing it to `REM @setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, edited `combined.bat` yields the following:

```
INPUT = 64_65_66_67_68_69_70_64

OUTPUT_A = @ABCDEF@

array[0] = !array[0]! = !char!
array[1] = !array[1]! = !char!
OUTPUT_B = !resultB!
```

As you can see, `OUTPUT_A` is now correct. However, the batch code for `OUTPUT_B` does not work properly anymore. I tried tinkering around with the script for a bit (i.e. placing `EnableDelayedExpansion` in different locations, etc.). I am still unable to get the script to yield correct output for both `OUTPUT_A` and `OUTPUT_B` at the same runtime.

**When providing a solution, please elaborate in respect to the script changes made to `combined.bat`.**

Comment: Well, you are right, the line `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is problematic here, because in the assignment `set alphabet=` there is an exclamation mark which is consumed by delayed expansion; try to put `^^!` instead of `!`, and also `^^^^` instead of `^`, in order to escape the `!` as well as the `^` from both expansion phases (normal `%` and delayed `!`). I did not check the rest of the code though...

Comment: `set errorlevel=0` may ruin further use of builtin `errorlevel` variable. Suggest removal, especially as you are setting and not using the variable anywhere.

Comment: @aschipfl I made the changes you suggested and it almost fixed everything.Thank you. The `!` / `33` conversion is still not working though. Trying to figure it out atm. @michael_heath I got rid of the errorlevel vars since I don't use them, as you suggested, in the original question

Comment: I suggested to use `^^^^` instead of `^`, but actually `^^` needs to be used instead because of the preceding `"`, which prevents such characters to be recognised as escape characters first; sorry for that! I did not check the other error you mentioned, but you have it solved yourself meanwhile anyway...

Comment: @aschipfl I noticed while trying to get everything working. Nonetheless, thanks!! Your comment definitely helped me get everything working in a shorter period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it all out and posted the solution script, as well as the script output.

I changed `alphabet` so that the `!` is now `^^!`, and the `^` is now `^^^`. This fixed a majority of the issues. However, there was still a bug where `33`s were not converting correctly to `!`s. In order to fix that, I had to make a change to the `:CHR` and `:ASCII` functions. The significant script edits for the solution are listed at the bottom of this post.

**Solution - ASCII Converting Batch Script (with all bug fixes):**

```
@echo off
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: define characters from 32 to 126
set alphabet= ^^!"#$%%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^^^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"

set testVar=64_65_66_67_68_69_70_64_32_33_34_126
echo INPUT = %testVar%
echo.

set resultA=

call :CHR 64
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
call :CHR 65        
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
call :CHR 66        
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
call :CHR 67        
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
call :CHR 68        
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
call :CHR 69        
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
call :CHR 70        
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
call :CHR 64        
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
call :CHR 32        
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
call :CHR 33        
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
call :CHR 34        
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
call :CHR 126
set resultA=!resultA!!char!
echo OUTPUT_A = !resultA!
echo.

set char=randomValueJustToInitFill
call :split "%testVar%" "_" array

set resultB=
:: Loop through the resulting array
for /L %%I in (0, 1, %array.ubound%) do (
    call :CHR !array[%%I]!
    echo array[%%I] = !array[%%I]! = !char!
    set resultB=!resultB!!char!
)
echo OUTPUT_B = !resultB!
echo.
goto :EOF

:CHR
:: valid range should be from 32 to 126 inclusive
if "%1"=="" goto :EOF
if %1 LSS 32 goto :EOF
if %1 GTR 126 goto :EOF

:: call function
call :ASCII %1 chr

:: print result, using ^ to escape special characters 
:: such as <, > and |
set char=!chr!

:: end the script
goto :EOF

:: sub-routine
:ASCII
        :: get the index
        set /a var=%1-32
        :: retrieve letter
        set character=!alphabet:~%var%,1!
    :: end the routine and return result as second parameter (out)
    set %2=!character!
@EXIT /B 0

:: split subroutine
:split <string_to_split> <split_delimiter> <array_to_populate>
:: populates <array_to_populate>
:: creates arrayname.length (number of elements in array)
:: creates arrayname.ubound (upper index of array)

set "_data=%~1"

:: replace delimiter with " " and enclose in quotes
set _data="!_data:%~2=" "!"

:: remove empty "" (comment this out if you need to keep empty elements)
set "_data=%_data:""=%"

:: initialize array.length=0, array.ubound=-1
set /a "%~3.length=0, %~3.ubound=-1"

for %%I in (%_data%) do (
    set "%~3[!%~3.length!]=%%~I"
    set /a "%~3.length+=1, %~3.ubound+=1"
)
@EXIT /B 0
@endlocal
```

**Output of Solution Script:**

```
INPUT = 64_65_66_67_68_69_70_64_32_33_34_126

OUTPUT_A = @ABCDEF@ !"~

array[0] = 64 = @
array[1] = 65 = A
array[2] = 66 = B
array[3] = 67 = C
array[4] = 68 = D
array[5] = 69 = E
array[6] = 70 = F
array[7] = 64 = @
array[8] = 32 =
array[9] = 33 = !
array[10] = 34 = "
array[11] = 126 = ~
OUTPUT_B = @ABCDEF@ !"~
```

**Changes to the `alphabet` variable:**

The following fixed a good bulk of the problem.

Changed

```
set alphabet= !"#$%%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
```

to

```
set alphabet= ^^!"#$%%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^^^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
```

**Changes to `:CHR` and `:ASCII` functions:**

The following fixed the bug where `33`s were not converting correctly to `!`s.

- Got rid of the local `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `endlocal &` specific to the `:ASCII` function.
- Using `set %2=!character!` instead of `set %2=^%character%`.
- Using `set char=!chr!` instead of `set char=^%chr%`.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this batch file example](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=32485#p32485) and [this one too](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=32495#p32495).