# Print Windows %PATH% with every entry on new line

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a task: print all entries of %PATH% variable on new line. For example:

```
C:\Program Files\
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32
```

and so on...

Comment: It sounds like an interesting task. What have you tried so far to actually make it happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Pretty print' windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471556/pretty-print-windows-path-variable-how-to-split-on-in-cmd-shell)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Solved: I used `echo %path:;=&echo(%`

Source: [*How do I view/see the PATH in a windows environment?*](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313231839/http://geekswithblogs.net/AskPaula/archive/2008/12/18/128035.aspx)  (the original link is dead, now linking to WebArchive)

Comment: @SteveValliere Sorry for VERY slow answer, but here's the source (for history: http://geekswithblogs.net/AskPaula/archive/2008/12/18/128035.aspx#548528)

Comment: Great answer! I would love an explanation on how and why it works :)

Comment: @Nom1fan it's explained how it works here: https://superuser.com/questions/1369142/how-this-windows-cmd-command-works/1369153#1369153

Comment: The initial `echo` should also be `echo.` for fully consistent behaviour across all elements of the path including the first.

Comment: Great answer. Sorting the output can be handy, e.g,: ```cmd /c "echo %path:;=&echo.%" | sort```

Comment: I use this command through a macro. From .bat file: `DOSKEY pathlist = echo %%PATH:;=^&echo.%%`

Comment: Re `echo.` (with dot) see [_SS64 – Echo a blank line_](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html#blank): "_Other [than ':'] command delimiters are available but have buggy side effects, for example `Echo.` will search for a file named "echo" (or echo.exe) in the current directory, if such a file is found that will raise an error. If the 'echo' file does not exist then the command does work, but this still makes `Echo.` slightly slower than `echo:` (In recent builds of WIndows 10 `Echo.` will always throw an error.)_"

Comment: You should use `echo(` instead, even `echo:` could fail with some arguments, like in `PATH=C:\windows;\..\..\..\Windows\System32\calc.exe` [ECHO. fails ...](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774&start=0#p4554)

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
SET count=1
:loop
FOR /f "tokens=%count%delims=;" %%i IN ("%path%") DO ECHO %%i&SET /a count+=1&GOTO loop
ECHO %count% entries found
```

Not hard - simply use TOKENS to select the token number until they run out. May want to echo `%%~i` to strip quoted paths if you want. count displayed because it's there.

Answer (score 0):

[Groosha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2032848/groosha)'s Answer works perfectly but it won't work with command "find".

Use following to print path in separate lines but only for specific word:

```
echo %path:;=|find "Windows"&echo(%
```

Above will print only the paths containing the word "Windows"

```
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32
```