# How to create a DOSKEY alias command to print Windows %PATH% with every entry on new line?

Tags: windows, cmd, echo, doskey

I have the same task as [Print Windows %PATH% with every entry on new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884892/print-windows-path-with-every-entry-on-new-line)

I have a task: print all entries of %PATH% variable on new line. For example:

```
C:\Program Files\
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32
```

and so on...

which is achievable by `echo %path:;=&echo.%` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15885269/7150888)

And I want to assign it to a command alias using [DOSKEY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey)

But the following script is failing for me

```
DOSKEY list=echo %path:;=&echo.%
```

Which just prints all of the paths while I'm defining the DOSKEY, and after that, when I try to invoke `list` command, it just doesn't work.

Comment: You have to escape the `&` special character as `^&`, and CMD's first pass environment-variable expansion has to be escaped. In a batch script we can escape `%` by doubling it. On the command line the best we can do is disrupt it by inserting a `^` character after the percent, since there shouldn't be an environment  variable named "^path". For example: `doskey list=echo %^path:;=^&echo.%`.

Comment: That said, doskey macros wrap the console's [`AddConsoleAlias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/addconsolealias) function, so they are of limited use. The console (conhost.exe) matches the alias source at the beginning of a processed read, and replaces it with the alias target. The target program (in this case cmd.exe) is not involved at all. Thus doskey macros can't work as real shell commands; we can't pipe to them, and we can't use them in batch scripts. It would be better if you created a "list.bat" batch script in a `PATH` directory.

Comment: @eryksun Does this mean that I cannot define a custom command to print all paths, each on separate line, without making a separate batch script?

Comment: It means you need a batch script if you want to do something like loop over the output. For example, if your command is in "list-path.bat", you can run `for /f "tokens=*" %p in ('list-path') do @echo %p` on the command line. That can't work with a console alias because the console would only match and replace "list-path" as the beginning of a line. Obviously it also can't work from a batch script, because that's reading from a disk file instead of the console.

Comment: Also, console aliases don't work in PowerShell (e.g. `doskey /exename=powershell.exe whichever=whatever`) since it uses a low-level console read instead a processed console read. It's no great loss because PowerShell supports real shell aliases and functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @eryksun you'll need to escape special chars.

Update: And to prevent a premature expanding - will use delayed expansion.

```
doskey list=cmd /v:on /c "for %p in ("!path:;=" "!") do @echo %~p"
```

An explanation of how this work: we can't use directly solution with `echo ^%path:;=^&echo.^%` because it's stored in macros already expanded. To prevent this I've tried to use delayed expansion (the part with `cmd /v:on /c`). It seemed almost working but without splitting on new lines (adding `&` for some reason doesn't work with delayed expansion).

Then I started to search a way to split `!path!` and found a neat trick with replacing `;` to `" "` (double quoted space) (`"!path:;=" "!"`). This splitting was good enough for a plain `for` (without `/f` option). The rest is obvious.

Comment: It works, but not as I wish it to. It statically substitutes "list" with "echo 1^&echo.2^&echo.3" and so on. Which makes it unusable for my case. For example, if I add new paths to the PATH, then I have to redefine the "list" macro again. Can we overcome this?

Comment: @LPVOID That was a challenge. Updated the answer.

Comment: It's working great! Thank you so much! :) Could you, please, explain why it works like this? Brief explanation of each term in the above command would be awesome!

Comment: @LPVOID I've added the explanation. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Your answer is really awesome! Thank you so much for your effort. :)