# How to echo filesize from list of absolute paths

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

I have a file "file_list.txt" containing absolute path of a list of files. Each line ends with a semicolon. The file appears like this.

```
"C:\Users\ab cd\AK\AK_PPF.pdf";
"C:\Users\ab cd\AK\AK_PPF.jpg";
"C:\Users\ab cd\AK\DL PAGE 1.jpg";
"C:\Users\ab cd\AK\dl pAGE 2.jpg";
"C:\Users\ab cd\AK\dl pAGE 3.jpg";
```

I wrote following code to echo the file size of each file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set v_file_list="file_list.txt"
FOR /F "delim=; tokens=1 usebackq" %%A IN (%v_file_list%) DO @echo %%~zA
```

When I run the batch file, it says **"delim=; tokens=1 usebackq" was unexpected at this time**
Please tell what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `delims` instead of `delim`. This also works in leading position.

Comment: +1 for identifying the syntax error, but there is still a potential problem. @ak28 - This solution will fail if path contains `;`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15923700/1012053) for an alternative bullet proof solution.

Answer (score 2):

Endoro identified your syntax error - the misspelled `DELIMS=;` option.

You have another potential problem: `;` is a valid character that can appear in a file or path name. `;` within a name is rare, but it does crop up now and again. Your `DELIMS=;` will corrupt (truncate) any path that contains `;`.

You should use an alternate technique to eliminate the unwanted trailing `;`.

You could use an expansion substring operation to remove the last character, but that would require setting and expanding a variable within the same loop, which would require either a CALL, or else delayed expansion. CALLs are expensive (slow), and delayed expansion will corrupt expansion of `%%A` if it contains `!` (another rare, but valid character for file names). So delayed expansion would have to be toggled on and off appropriately.

There is a simpler solution that relies on the fact that your file paths are enclosed in quotes, and the `;` is outside the quotes. You can use an additional FOR statement to remove the trailing `;` because `;` is a token delimiter for the simple FOR statement (without /F option).

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (%v_file_list%) do for %%F in (%%A) do @echo %%~zF
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know if there is a solution for `;`in file/path names in batch if the paths are not enclosed in double quotes, eg. in the %path% variable.

Comment: @Endoro - Oh, but there is :-) jeb came up with an insanely clever algorithm at ['Pretty print' windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168/1012053)

Answer (score 0):

AT least people in this area are largely constructive - bouncing ideas around rather than systematically voting down /to delete/close questions and answers that don't like.

Here's my contrib, FWIW:

Original problem, with trailing semicolons:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
ECHO.== file_list.txt ==========
TYPE file_list.txt
set v_file_list="file_list.txt"
ECHO.== batch run ==========
FOR /F "usebackqdelims=" %%A IN (%v_file_list%) DO (
SET filename=%%A
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%s IN (!filename!) DO (endlocal&ECHO %%s %%~zs)
)
ECHO.== actual DIR list ==========
DIR /a-d "u:\users\ab cd\ak"
```

Run results:

```
== file_list.txt ==========
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.pdf";
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.jpg";
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 1.jpg";
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 2.jpg";
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 3.jpg";
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg;";
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg";
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!page;4.jpg;";
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl%page%;4.jpg;";
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!pag!e;4.jpg;";
== batch run ==========
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.pdf" 21031
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.jpg" 428
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 1.jpg" 54338
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 2.jpg" 83344
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 3.jpg" 14036
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg;" 22498
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg" 55506
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!page;4.jpg;" 4007
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl%page%;4.jpg;" 5310
"u:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!pag!e;4.jpg;" 4693
== actual DIR list ==========
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0466-0000

 Directory of u:\users\ab cd\ak

10/04/2013  20:25            21,031 ak_ppf.pdf
10/04/2013  20:25               428 ak_ppf.jpg
10/04/2013  20:25            54,338 dl page 1.jpg
10/04/2013  20:26            83,344 dl page 2.jpg
10/04/2013  20:26            14,036 dl page 3.jpg
10/04/2013  20:41            22,498 dl page;4.jpg;
10/04/2013  20:40            55,506 dl page;4.jpg
10/04/2013  20:49             4,007 dl!page;4.jpg;
10/04/2013  20:50             5,310 dl%page%;4.jpg;
10/04/2013  21:31             4,693 dl!pag!e;4.jpg;
              10 File(s)        265,191 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   2,146,500,608 bytes free
```

General example, text file is filename-only:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
ECHO.== file_list_raw.txt ==========
TYPE file_list_raw.txt
set v_file_list="file_list_raw.txt"
ECHO.== batch run ==========
FOR /F "usebackqdelims=" %%A IN (%v_file_list%) DO (
SET filename="%%~A"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%s IN (!filename!) DO (endlocal&ECHO %%s %%~zs)
)
ECHO.== actual DIR list ==========
DIR /a-d "u:\users\ab cd\ak"
```

Run results:

```
== file_list_raw.txt ==========
U:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.pdf
U:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.jpg
U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 1.jpg
U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 2.jpg
U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 3.jpg
U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg;
U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg
U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!page;4.jpg;
U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl%page%;4.jpg;
U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!pag!e;4.jpg;
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.pdf"
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.jpg"
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 1.jpg"
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 2.jpg"
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 3.jpg"
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg;"
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg"
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!page;4.jpg;"
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl%page%;4.jpg;"
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!pag!e;4.jpg;"
== batch run ==========
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.pdf" 21031
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.jpg" 428
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 1.jpg" 54338
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 2.jpg" 83344
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 3.jpg" 14036
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg;" 22498
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg" 55506
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!page;4.jpg;" 4007
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl%page%;4.jpg;" 5310
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!pag!e;4.jpg;" 4693
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.pdf" 21031
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\ak_ppf.jpg" 428
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 1.jpg" 54338
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 2.jpg" 83344
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page 3.jpg" 14036
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg;" 22498
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl page;4.jpg" 55506
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!page;4.jpg;" 4007
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl%page%;4.jpg;" 5310
"U:\users\ab cd\ak\dl!pag!e;4.jpg;" 4693
== actual DIR list ==========
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0466-0000

 Directory of u:\users\ab cd\ak

10/04/2013  20:25            21,031 ak_ppf.pdf
10/04/2013  20:25               428 ak_ppf.jpg
10/04/2013  20:25            54,338 dl page 1.jpg
10/04/2013  20:26            83,344 dl page 2.jpg
10/04/2013  20:26            14,036 dl page 3.jpg
10/04/2013  20:41            22,498 dl page;4.jpg;
10/04/2013  20:40            55,506 dl page;4.jpg
10/04/2013  20:49             4,007 dl!page;4.jpg;
10/04/2013  20:50             5,310 dl%page%;4.jpg;
10/04/2013  21:31             4,693 dl!pag!e;4.jpg;
              10 File(s)        265,191 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   2,146,500,608 bytes free
```

The code really isn't much different from that already posted and remarks made in those posts.