# Return each item on a single line defined in %PATH% via windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, command, command-prompt

I would like to like to view each item on a single line that are defined in %PATH% environment variable.
I have used the following

```
for %A in ("%path:;=" "%") do @echo %A
```

It returns each item in a single line, but with double quotes around them as shown below.

```
"C:\Windows\System32"
"C:\Windows\system32\Wbem"
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\"
```

How do I print them without the double quotes? I tried using single quotes in the command, but couldn't get it right. (There are spaces in paths in some of the entires in %PATH%)

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Pretty print' windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471556/pretty-print-windows-path-variable-how-to-split-on-in-cmd-shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ECHO %path:;=&ECHO(%
```

:) :)

---

Edit for expansion.

The syntax `%var:string1=string2%` replaces all `string1` with `string2` within `var` hence this command is resolved to

```
echo directory1&echo(directory2&echo(directory3...
```

at each `;` which is the separator used between directorynames in `%path%`.

The `echo(` is a trick construct. There are many characters which are ignored to one extent or another DIRECTLY following `echo`. `SPACE` is the most common, but the command `ECHO` will show the `ECHO` state - `ECHO is on/off`. `ECHO(` however will show nothing (other than any characters following the `(` ).

As  it happens, my `path` ends with `;` so if I was to use `&echo` to replace `;` then the line would be resolved to `....echo dirlast&echo` and produce the `ECHO` state as a last line. Using `echo(` neatly overcomes this problem.