# find a file in path, and if not there, some known locations

Tags: batch-file, path

I need to find a specific file location (java in my case) in the system. For that I would search first through %PATH% variable with and excellent script from here: ['Pretty print' windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471556/pretty-print-windows-path-variable-how-to-split-on-in-cmd-shell?lq=1)

But if command is not found in path (OR, it is found, but not suitable - in my case i am looking for 32bit java installation in 64bit environment, and normally 64bit java is in the path) i have a set of location to look into as well (namely (x86) in the program files name).

To make it more usable i'd like to do it with calling out a function in bat, but here's where i fail.

this far i have:

```
::@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set FILENAME=java
set CMDLINE=-version -d32
set JAVAPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin"

call :Checkpath "%path%"

if "%JAVALOC%!="" goto :EOF

call :Checkpath %JAVAPATH%

goto :EOF

:Checkpath
REM THIS following line seems to be the problem
set var="%~1" 
set "var=%var:"=""%"
set "var=%var:^=^^%"
set "var=%var:&=^&%"
set "var=%var:|=^|%"
set "var=%var:<=^<%"
set "var=%var:>=^>%"
set "var=%var:;=^;^;%"
set var=%var:""="%
set "var=%var:"=""Q%"
set "var=%var:;;="S"S%"
set "var=%var:^;^;=;%"
set "var=%var:""="%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=!var:"Q=!"
for %%a in ("!var:"S"S=";"!") do (
  if "!!"=="" endlocal
  if %%a neq "" echo %%~a\%FILENAME% %CMDLINE%
  if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 (
    SET JAVALOC=%%a
  )
)


:EOF
echo %JAVALOC%
```

It doesn't work - without the function calling, everything is great with the script, passing path as

```
set var=%path%
```

but using in function, it just gives the full path variable in the first iteration of FOR loop.

Can anyone point me to a direction what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:checkPath
    rem Retrieve argument
    set "var=%~1"

    rem iterate over the list. ; is a separator in a list
    for %%a in ( %var% ) do (
        set "directory=%%~a"
        ....
        ....
    )
```

This will handle all the usual cases.

BUT, the "correct" way of locating java in windows machine is to ask windows.

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Where to find java information in registry
    set javaKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment

    rem Get current java version
    set javaVersion=
    for /f "tokens=3" %%v in ('reg query "%javaKey%" /v "CurrentVersion" ^| find /i "CurrentVersion"') do (
        set "javaVersion=%%v"
    )
    if "%javaVersion%"=="" goto endProcess

    rem Get javahome for current java version
    for /f "tokens=2,*" %%d in ('reg query "%javaKey%\%javaVersion%" /v "JavaHome" ^| find /i "JavaHome"') do (
        set javaDir=%%e
    )

    rem You need 32 bit version. Check for it
    rem If there is a separate ProgramFiles for 32 bit, adapt path

    if not "%programfiles%"=="%programfiles(x86)%" (
        set "javaDir=!javaDir:%programFiles%=%programFiles(x86)%!"
    )

    echo JAVA_HOME=%javaDir%

:endProcess 
    endlocal
```