# How do I get Windows cmd FOR to 'play-nice' with drag-n-drop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, drag-and-drop, msys

I had a very straight forward little batch script.  The design outline is simple enough ... I want to touch every file '*dropped*'.

1. There is a Windows short-cut on the desktop that calls a batch (.cmd) script.
2. Select some files with Windows Explorer
3. Drag-n-Drop the selection onto either the short-cut icon or the command file directly.
4. The script loops over the list of files dropped onto the icon.
5. The script uses the **FOR** command to call the command one file at a time.

Anyway there are several circumstances where the result is strange (to say the least).  The worst example is an infinite loop that crashes cmd.exe.  Here is the command file.  There are extra prints and pauses here so I can watch the behaviour.

```sh
  @echo off
  @title  touch
  @echo.
  cd > z:\$$$\base.tmp
  set /p base= < z:\$$$\base.tmp
  @rem
  @echo  ^  folder: %base%
  @echo  ^  INPUT:  [%*]
  @echo.
  @pause
  @echo.
  for /d  %%x  in  (%*)  DO (
      @echo ^    RAW:      [%%x]
      @echo ^    each --^>  [%%~x]
      @echo ^    each --^>  [%%~fx]
      attrib "%%~fx"
      touch "%%~fx"
    echo.
    @pause
    echo.
)
@echo.
@echo ^  [done]
@echo.
@pause
```

The most problematic output is a source of confusion to me, see: example 1.  I put the **attrib** command in because it is a 'tame' system .exe.

When you comment-out the "touch" command, the look works with just **attrib** *most of* the time.  The only thing I can say for sure is that file names with spaces cause problems.  For example in the echo-ed "***each***" lines, I've seen examples like:

- `each --> [Z:\tmp\"Z:\tmp\C++ Recipes.pdf"]`
- `"G:\_xfer_\-m"`

The first seems to be a problem with the FOR loop expansion and how it deals with quotes(").  While the second appears to be a out of bounds error with the MSYS  touch.exe command.

There's also something fish that goes on when you pass a link (short-cut) file to the script.

I've tried many different versions of both the FOR syntax and the loop-variable escaping to side-step the issue.  After all my primary purpose is to have a GUI touch command.  My first question for the brains trust is:

1. What is the appropriate FOR and loop-variable expansion to use for this?

As well, since it has become a mystery ....

2. How does the infinite loop occur and is there a way to prevent it?
3. Does someone have a link for documentation and/or examples of FOR with a drag-n-drop with Window?
4. How can the script just show: 
       `Working folder ...`
       `G:\_xfer_`
   When the string: "Working folder", which is NOT in the .cmd script.  And, there was once a version that had the command: `echo Working folder:`

It it helps, I put a small script called, "drop.cmd" below as well.  As a final point, I suspect there's a bug in the MSYS /GNU  command-line handler for Windows:

- It seem that, When the `*args` that was passed contains a string with unbalanced quotes -- It can go off the reservation.

I get similar output to that in example 1, below from the MSYS **touch** and from **tail** commands.

I was about to sign-off.  There is one more thing, to consider.  Does anyone have a script or diagnostic I might use to 'unravel' this *ball-of-wool*?

### example 1

```
   folder: G:\_xfer_
   INPUT:  ["G:\_xfer_\00__zip (on D).lnk" G:\_xfer_\#trash.lnk]

Press any key to continue . . .

    RAW:      ["G:\_xfer_\00__zip (on D).lnk"]
    each -->  [G:\_xfer_\00__zip (on D).lnk]
    each -->  [G:\_xfer_\00__zip (on D).lnk]
A            G:\_xfer_\00__zip (on D).lnk
  all ... G:\_xfer_\00__zip (on D).lnk
  one ... G:\_xfer_\00__zip
  two ... (on


   Working folder ...
G:\_xfer_

touch -m -c  "G:\_xfer_\-m"

   Working folder ...
G:\_xfer_

touch -m -c  "G:\_xfer_\-m"
    :
    :
```

And eventually crashed with a stackoverflow!

### drop.cmd

```
@echo off
@title  %~1
@echo.
cd > z:\$$$\base.tmp
set /p base= < z:\$$$\base.tmp
@rem
@echo  ^  drop folder: %base%
@echo  ^  INPUT:       [%*]
@echo.
@pause
rem
@echo.
for   %%x  in  (%*)  DO ( 
    @echo ^    RAW:      [%%x]
    @echo ^    each --^>  [%%~x]
    @echo.
    @pause
)
@echo.
@echo ^  [done]
@echo.
@pause
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a bug in the mingw command interpreter"? There's actually no such thing, but even if you really mead _MSYS_ shell, you are not using it, because you are using cmd.exe batch file syntax, so the command interpreter is _Microsoft's_ cmd.exe.

Comment: What do you mean by "the mingw touch command"? Once again, there's no such thing, but there _is_ an _MSYS_ touch command. However, if it is this which you are using, you are using it improperly ... it is not intended to be used other than within a _properly_ initialized MSYS shell process context. You are trying to use it directly within a cmd.exe process context, with no MSYS process context in sight. Such usage is definitively unsupported, so it's hardly unexpected that it may not work as you would like. If you just want a no-frills touch for cmd.exe, use `>> filename`.

Comment: You didn't tell us how your first Batch file is called. If it is `touch.bat`, then when the first file is processed, the `touch "%%~fx"` command cause to recursively call itself in an endless loop that eventually crash by stack overflow

Comment: Thanks Aacini -- Actually no, I considered this.  The .CMD file is started by dragging onto a file called: `touche.cmd`, either directly on the file or via the short-cut on the desktop.

Comment: @KeithMarshall ... thank you for pointing-out both items.  Point taken.  The problem is with the FOR/drag-n-drop part of the script however.

Answer (score 3):

Getting a batch file handle dropped files can be sometimes difficult. Any dragged file with spaces in its name will be quoted, but a file with special characters (`&`) but without spaces will not be quoted. This will lead to problems with the parser handling the arguments to the file using `%*`.

But taking the [code from jeb' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168/2861476) and [polished by @dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7940444/2861476) to solve the problem of [*"Pretty print windows `%path%` variable"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5471556/2861476) (thank you both), and retrieving the arguments from `%*` only when called from command line (where arguments *"should"* be well formed) or from `%cmdcmdline%` (that hold the command line used to start the current `cmd` instance) when dropped, we can do something like

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "var="

    rem Determine call origin
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    call :detectDrop !cmdcmdline!
    endlocal
    if not errorlevel 1 goto :dropped

:commandLine
    rem Invoked from command line
    set "dropped="
    if "%~1"=="" goto done
    set var=%*
    set "var=%var:"=""%"
    goto :process

:dropped
    rem Invoked from explorer
    set "dropped=1"
    set "var=%cmdcmdline:"=""%"
    set "var=%var:*/c """"=%"
    set "var=%var:*"" =%"
    set "var=%var:~0,-2%"

:process
    if not defined var goto :done

    rem Adapted from dbenham's answer at [https://stackoverflow.com/a/7940444/2861476]

    set "var=%var:^=^^%"
    set "var=%var:&=^&%"
    set "var=%var:|=^|%"
    set "var=%var:<=^<%"
    set "var=%var:>=^>%"
    set "var=%var: =^ ^ %"
    set var=%var:""="%
    set "var=%var:"=""Q%"
    set "var=%var:  ="S"S%"
    set "var=%var:^ ^ = %"
    set "var=%var:""="%"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "var=!var:"Q=!"
    for %%a in ("!var:"S"S=" "!") do ( 
        if "!!"=="" endlocal

        rem Here we have a reference to the passed/dropped element
        if %%a neq "" echo "%%~fa"

    )
    goto :done

:detectDrop cmdcmdline
    if /i "%~1"=="%comspec%" if /i "%~2"=="/c" exit /b 0
    exit /b 1

:done    
    if defined dropped ( pause & exit )
```

**note**: sorry, not thoroughly tested. Maybe there is some case that will make it fail.

Comment: Would it be possible to extend this to also work with dropping folders and then parsing the containing files? And even recursively with folders within folders and all contained files within?