# for %a in ("%path:;=";"%") do @echo %~a

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

In Windows, when each of the PATH variables need to be listed on a single line then the command to be used is `for %a in ("%path:;=";"%") do @echo %~a` can be executed.

I don't understand, what does `"%path:;=";"%"` do?

Comment: basically it splits your path variable by using the delimiter ";", but it is interesting why `%path` does not take a second `%` like here `%path%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows batch files, you can do string substitution in variables using the syntax

```
%var:search=replace%
```

In your case, the variable is `path`, the search is `;` and the replacement is `";"`

```
      v ......... search 
%path:;=";"%
        ^^^ ..... replace
```

That way each semicolon in the variable contents is replaced by the same semicolon, but with a double quote in each side. Including an starting and ending quotes around the expression

```
"%path:;=";"%"
```

every semicolon delimited element in the `path` variable is now quoted

```
 c:\windows ; c:\windows\system32 ; c:\windows\system32\wbem ; c:\other folder
v          vvv                   vvv                        vvv               v
"c:\windows";"c:\windows\system32";"c:\windows\system32\wbem";"c:\other folder"
```

Now there is a list of quoted strings separated by a semicolon delimiter.

This string is processed by a `for` command that will process each delimited element storing it inside the `%a` replaceable parameter and executing the code inside the `do` clause for each value, echoing to console the content of the replaceable parameter without quotes (`%~a`)

All this to be able to enumerate the different directories in the `path` variable because it probably will contain other characters (ex. spaces) that are handled as delimiters by the `for` command.

Comment: This works as long as there are no quotes in the path itself and when no single directory of the path contains a semicolon (it's a legal character for a directory). ['Pretty print' windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5471556/463115)

Comment: @jeb, Maybe I should have included a warning in the answer, but as the question is about the meaning of the expression I left it out. Thank you anyway. I already know your post, well, I borrowed the code for [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31358421/2861476).

Answer (score 2):

It takes the value of the `%path%` variable and substitutes each occurrence of `;` character with `";"`. For more details see the output of `set /?` in command prompt.