# How to parse multiple file name arguments passed to a Windows batch (.BAT) file with file name containing commas?

Tags: for-loop, parsing, batch-file, arguments, drop

I'm trying to echo files dropped on a batch file using command **FOR**, but this method is broken if a file has commas `,` in it's name.

Example of files being dropped:

```
Testfile.txt
Pictures,photos,GIFS.zip
Personal documents.7z
```

Code:

```
for %%a in (%*) do echo ---  "%%a"
```

The resulting echos should be the previous file list, but instead it gives me something like this:

```
testfile.txt
Pictures
photos
GIFS.zip
Personal documents.7z
```

It separated `Pictures,photos,GIFS.zip` by it's commas.

How do I solve this?

Another thing: I noticed that if instead type the batch in a command line with those example files as arguments, it behaves correctly by maintaining the zip filename whole **IF** I put it between `""`. So I guess the solution should be to make sure every `%*` comes with surrounding `""`, but how do I do that if they are already wrongly separated at the source, meaning a `echo %1 & echo %2 & echo %3` will show `pictures,photos,GIFS.zip` as already separated strings?

I can't believe that I can't retrieve filenames dropped in a batch file if those have commas in their names.

Comment: The drag-and-drop interaction between Windows Explorer and Command Prompt is *terribly* designed, file names only become quoted in case they contain _spaces_, but other token separators (like `,`, `;`, `=`) or characters with special meaning (like `&`, `(`, `)`, `^`) do not become protected by quotes (unless there is at least a _space_ in addition). Perhaps you are interested in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31358421)…

Comment: @aschipfl So that's it, it has to have at least a space,  I forgot to remove one from "Pictures,photos, GIFS.zip" when I wrote that here, that's why it certainly worked on your side and not on mine.
I'm going to check the link you provided, thanks.

Comment: @Pedro: did the link aschipfl provided help you? Let us know, so we can link your question to that one to help future searchers with the same problem.

Comment: @Stephan, the code worked, I will adapt it to my script. Frankly I didn't think it was possible to do that since the problem was at the root of the parsing, but I guess there are indeed batch wizards, lol.   Yes, it provided newinsights to me. Thanks aschipfl