# Traverse path variable with FOR in Windows

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

My faithful path traversal method no longer works - it sees spaces as delimiters. It's been a while since I needed to do batch programming.
When using the `FOR` loop, the only one that allows delimiters are the `FOR /F` option.
I don't want to create a temporary file containing the path, was hoping to do something like below:

> ```
> C:\Users>for /f "delims=;" %i in %path% do echo %i
> C:\Program was unexpected at this time.
>
> C:\Users>for /f "delims=;" %i in (%path%) do echo %i
> \Common was unexpected at this time.
>
> C:\Users>for /f "delims=;" %i in 'foo;bar' do echo %i
> 'foo was unexpected at this time.
> ```

Comment: Please do not insert your chosen solution into the question! I did a [rollback](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38913232/4). Accepting an answer clearly shows which solution worked out best for you. Thank you!

Comment: Closely related: ['Pretty print' windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5471556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (^"!path:^;^=^
% Do NOT remove this line %
!^") do echo %%a
```

Output example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static
C:\Program Files\Bandizip\7z
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a standard `for` loop rather than `for /F "delims=;"` with some smart sub-string replacement:

```
for %I in ("%PATH:;=";"%") do @echo %~I
```

Supposing `PATH` contains `C:\Program Files\someapp1\app1.exe;C:\Program Files\someapp2\app2.exe;C:\Program Files\someapp3\app3.exe`, you will receive the following output:

> ```
> C:\Program Files\someapp1\app1.exe
> C:\Program Files\someapp2\app2.exe
> C:\Program Files\someapp3\app3.exe
> ```

This works only in case none of the paths are surrounded by `"` and none of them contains `;`.

In a batch script the code must be changed to this:

```
for %%I in ("%PATH:;=";"%") do @echo %%~I
```

Answer (score 1):

A perfect solution must be able to differentiate between `;` delimiters and quoted `;` literals.

Here is a very robust solution that always works using [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'jrepl "([^;\q]+|\q.*?(\q|$))+" $0 /x /jmatch /s path'
) do echo(%%F
```

If all you want to do is list each folder, one line per folder, then simply remove the FOR /F loop

```
call jrepl "([^;\q]+|\q.*?(\q|$))+" $0 /x /jmatch /s path
```

If you want a pure batch solution that always works, then you can use:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "var=%var:"=""%"
set "var=%var:^=^^%"
set "var=%var:&=^&%"
set "var=%var:|=^|%"
set "var=%var:<=^<%"
set "var=%var:>=^>%"
set "var=%var:;=^;^;%"
set var=%var:""="%
set "var=%var:"=""Q%"
set "var=%var:;;="S"S%"
set "var=%var:^;^;=;%"
set "var=%var:""="%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=!var:"Q=!"
for %%a in ("!var:"S"S=";"!") do (
  if "!!"=="" endlocal
  if %%a neq "" echo %%~a
)
```

The above is a slightly improved version of [jeb's original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168/1012053)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Instructions from [Mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb-community-edition-from-the-command-interpreter) .

```
cd C:\
md "\data\db"
```

After this step, you could once check in `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\<Version Number>\bin\mongod.cfg"`

there you could see, a default option of DBPath

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: %MONGO_DATA_PATH%
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:
```

Now add the `%MONGO_DATA_PATH%` variable in Environment variables of your system as key, where value is the file path ( where you have created the data/db folder)

now you could start mongod process without passing an argument of dbPath.