# Meaning of this cmd one-liner that pretty prints %PATH%

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm utterly confused by this one-liner from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471556/pretty-print-windows-path-variable-how-to-split-on-in-cmd-shell), that pretty prints the `%PATH%` variable.

> `ECHO.%PATH:;= & ECHO.%`

Could you break this one-liner up, and explain what each part means?

For example,

- How is `%PATH%` split on semicolons?
- The `PATH` variable is normally referred to as `%PATH%`. What's the syntax used here?
- What do`ECHO.%` and `:;=` mean?
- Where is the *"for each line, echo it out"* logic?

I'd also appreciate it if you could point to any resources that explain the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first check this: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

the semicolon means that a substring  in the variable will be replaced.First is the old substring then equal sign,then is the new one.

In this case every semicolon is replaced with the command `ECHO.` which prints a new line. 
The ampersand is used to execute more command on a single line.

As there is no delayed expansion the expansion of the variable will execute also the echo commands.

Answer (score 2):

**An example (underscore denotes space)**

Say `%PATH%` is `a;b;c`

The expression `%PATH:;=_&_ECHO.%` replaces each `;` with `_&_ECHO.` (see answer by  @npocmaka)

This gives `a_&_ECHO.b_&_ECHO.c`

Since `%PATH%` does not begin with a semicolon, we must prepend `ECHO.` to the above expression to make sure the first directory `a` is printed. This gives

> `ECHO.%PATH:;=_&_ECHO.%`

which expands to `ECHO.a_&_ECHO.b_&_ECHO.c`

---

**`ECHO.` why the dot?**

Say `%PATH%` is `a;b;;c`

If we use `ECHO_` we will get

```
a
b
ECHO is on.
c
```

If we use `ECHO.` we will get

```
a
b

c
```

From [this discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/08e80dec-f915-49ab-ac76-c0c5e33bbe75/echo-command-in-cmdexe?forum=ITCG),

> `ECHO.` is used to get the ECHO statement to output a blank line.  In
>   accordance with its design, the ECHO issued blank or with just white
>   space after the command text, outputs the current 'echo' status, that
>   is ON or OFF.