# Does the current directory exist in %PATH%?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I tried so many possibilities to achieve this but I keep on getting errors.

I dont know why I can't pass `%CD%` and `%PATH%` to `FINDSTR`.

```
@echo off
findstr %cd% %path%
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

The result is `findstr` can't take value from `%path%` because it is not a file so I tried to `echo` it to file.

```
@echo off
echo %path% > path.txt
findstr %cd% path.txt
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

For now `findstr` could open `path.txt` but couldn't get the string to compare. The `%cd%` didn't appear to work so I tried to put it manually like this:

```
@echo off
echo %path% > path.txt
findstr c:\foo path.txt
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

It works!

So how can I get the current directory value and pass the value to `findstr`? or more plainly, how do I detect if the current directory exists within %PATH% variable.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to find out if the current directory is part of your path?

Comment: @J.Baoby yeah, like that. i already edit my question.

Comment: Simple: `if "!path:%cd%=!" neq "%path%" echo Current directory IS in PATH`, but don't forget to include `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` line before...

Comment: That code with added case insensitivity is in my answer @Aacini but apparently `its not work only echo not found.`

Comment: You have gotten help from some if the best when it comes to batch-files. If none of their code is working then it comes down to a PEBKAC error.

Comment: @Compo: Ops! I didn't saw it... **`:(`** The case insensivity is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (echo "%path:;=" "%") do if /i "%cd%"=="%%a" echo "found it"
```

should do this for most situations *but* there are exceptions.

`path` *may* contain relative paths (`.` or `..`) which will not be detected.

`path` *may* contain `"some;directory"` which will not play nicely

and there is no requirement that the drivename appears in `path`.

So - use with caution.

Comment: its not work. is there an alternative findstr console out there?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following small example script which uses `FIND` and `FINDSTR` with conditionals and also an `IF`/`ELSE`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo(%PATH%|Find/I "%CD%;">Nul&&(Echo(Found)||Echo(Not Found
Timeout 2
Echo(%PATH%|FindStr/I "%CD%;">Nul&&(Echo(Found)||Echo(Not Found
Timeout 2
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If /I "!PATH:%CD%;=!"=="!PATH!" (Echo(Not Found) Else Echo(Found
EndLocal
Timeout -1
```

*So that is three different attempts at the same task, how do they work for you?*

Comment: i try your code. its not work only echo not found. even in path theres the value.

Comment: it keep struggling for now haha.

Comment: Please post the output of `Echo(%PATH%`

Comment: **I want to see it**, if you don't post it, after four different solutions as well as your own have failed, then you are unlikely to receive further help!

Answer (score 0):

There is not any universal, simple, direct way to check if the current folder is included in the `path` variable using `findstr` because for each referenced folder inside `path`: it can be an absolute or relative reference, it can include or not an ending backslash, it can be or not quoted, it can include or not special characters, it can include (if quoted) semicolons, ...

In top of that, in order to use `findstr` to do the check you will need to handle problems with the backslash characters as they are used as escape characters in regular expressions but also in literals when preceding a non alphanumeric character. Try

```dos
echo x:\_uno\ | findstr /L /c:"x:\_uno" && echo Yes || echo No
```

So, you will need to process each value inside the `path` variable dealing with quoted semicolons, special characters, backslashes, ...

Fortunately this was solved by [Jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168/2861476) and [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7940444/2861476) in the ['Pretty print' windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5471556/2861476). Using their code to enumerate the elements it the `path` variable, and the approach in the [Magoo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46743050/2861476) answer in this question, we can write somenthing like

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Flag variable. Assume current folder is not present in path variable 
    set "present="

    rem This code uses:
    rem  Q: Pretty print %path%       https://stackoverflow.com/q/5471556
    rem     A:  Jeb answer            https://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168
    rem     A:  dbenham enhancement   https://stackoverflow.com/a/7940444
    set "var=%path:"=""%"
    set "var=%var:^=^^%"
    set "var=%var:&=^&%"
    set "var=%var:|=^|%"
    set "var=%var:<=^<%"
    set "var=%var:>=^>%"
    set "var=%var:;=^;^;%"
    set var=%var:""="%
    set "var=%var:"=""Q%"
    set "var=%var:;;="S"S%"
    set "var=%var:^;^;=;%"
    set "var=%var:""="%"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=!var:"Q=!"

    rem Get a reference to current folder (%%c) and check against each 
    rem delimited value inside the processed variable
    for %%c in (.) do for %%a in ("!var:"S"S=";"!") do (
        if "!!"=="" endlocal
        if %%a neq "" for %%b in ("%%~fa.") do (
            if /i "%%~fb"=="%%~fc" set "present=1"
        )
    )

    if defined present (
        echo Current folder is INCLUDED in path variable
    ) else (
        echo Current folder is NOT included in path variable
    )
```

For each element in the path, resolve it to the full qualified path and check against the full qualified path of the current folder.

Comment: thx for reply. i make discuss to move to real desktop programming. i see so many disadvantage batch file as i through this script.

Comment: @Nichie, batch files are very useful, and for a lot of tasks they are the simplest approach, but sometimes they are a wrench we use to hammer a nail, it can solve the problem but it is not the right tool. But in this case, for the problem in your question, you will have to deal with the same indicated problems whatever the language you decide to use.

Comment: the purpose my script is i want to act like antivirus that find something in list that i don't want and kill it. or block it. but the more i dig in batch. i see the disadvantage  of batch files its not standalone app. it need cmd.exe to execute. and it can't mask or hide itself in process.