# Why does comparing an environment variable value with a string result in an error message?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I tried to compare current date on being equal to a specific date using this code:

```
@echo on
if %date%=="Sun 10/15/2017" ( echo "Today is Sunday" ) else ( echo "Today is Unknown" )
pause
```

But on execution of the batch file I get just output the error message:

> 10/15/2017=="Sun 10/15/2017" was unexpected at this time.

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Nichie, please update [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46744276/6738015) with the solution you found, and also post the information requested in the [previous question to that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46743856/6738015) too! Members are often reluctant to provide responses to those who fail to follow reasonable requests etc. In response to this question you haven't matched the doublequotes on either side of the comparison and we have no idea of the format of your `%date%` variable!

Comment: You have quotes on one side of the comparison to protect spaces. Why do you think you wouldn't need them on the other side?

Answer (score 1):

The date environment variable reference `%date%` is replaced by Windows command interpreter during the preprocessing state by the region (country) dependent string **before** the **IF** command is executed at all.

On running the batch file from within a command prompt window it can be seen that the **IF** command line is after preprocessing:

```
if Sun 10/15/2017=="Sun 10/15/2017" ( echo "Today is Sunday" ) else ( echo "Today is Unknown" )
```

So the syntax of **IF** command is not correct after environment variable expansion because there is `Sun` as first argument, a space and `Sun 10/15/2017=="Sun 10/15/2017"` being interpreted as unexpected operator.

Whenever comparing strings it is recommended to use double quotes as only within a double quoted string the space character is not interpreted as argument separator. And the characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~|<> `` are also interpreted as literal characters within a double quoted string.

The double quotes are also compared by **IF** on running the string comparison. So it is needed that both compared strings are enclosed in double quotes.

```
@echo off
if "%DATE%"=="Sun 10/15/2017" ( echo "Today is Sunday." ) else ( echo "Today is unknown." )
pause
```

Another solution if region dependent date really contains the abbreviated weekday too.

```
@echo off
if not "%DATE:Sun=%"=="%DATE%" ( echo "Today is Sunday." ) else ( echo "Today is unknown." )
pause
```

This batch file compares the current date string with all case-insensitive occurrences of `Sun` being replaced by nothing with unmodified current date string. The string substitution is successful only on date string containing weekday abbreviation `Sun` and in this case the two compared strings are not equal.

On my computer the **IF** condition is never true as `%DATE%` expands to a date string not containing weekday according to configuration in Windows **Region and Language** settings.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`