# Working of Path variable wrt position of new path

Tags: node.js, path, environment-variables

I was modifying my PATH variable in order to configure it for node js.

On appending `C:\Tools\nodejs;` to the beginning of PATH, `node -v` and `npm -v` executed correctly, but on appending it to the end of PATH, neither of the commands were recognized.

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely an error in your path somewhere. As the path is probably traversed from left to right, any error could make it fail or incorrectly split the paths in the PATH variable.

Try and [pretty print](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5471556/589259) the PATH and see if anything is wrong.