# Print a Certain Line in PATH Environment Variable using BATCH File

Tags: batch-file

In environment variables, I have multiple paths stored in PATH.

I would like to be able to print a single certain path.

Is it possible to print a path that contains a certain string? If not, how about printing only the first line in path?

Comment: To print only the first line is easy, the PATH variable has only one line.

Comment: Oh. I mean the first path that is stored in Path.

Comment: Then you should split the PATH into parts, see ['Pretty print' windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5472168/463115)