# Showing git branch in ConEMU

Tags: git, conemu

Is there a way to show the branch in git somewhere visually (background or similiar) in ConEmu?

Comment: Background? Similar? Where do you want to see branch? What shell at last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Disclaimer #1
>
> ConEmu is not a shell, so it does not provide "shell features" like tab-completion, command history and others.

Usually, Git information like branch or amount of changes is displayed in the command line prompt, for example `C:\path\to\repository [branch|+2~4-6]>`. This is done by the executing shell, not the console frame.

As far as I know, the standard Windows command prompt (CMD) does not support modifying that. The bash that comes with [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.com/) already supports that perfectly though; and for PowerShell there are numerous extensions for Git, most notably [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git).

Answer (score 53):

Git branch can be visible in plain cmd or Far Manager prompt.

[image: GIT branch in cmd prompt]

All magic is done with special ANSI sequences ("Inject ConEmuHk" and "ANSI X3.64 ..." options must be checked).
I
Run `GitShowBranch /i` to install showing branch, `GitShowBranch /u` to uninstall.

Also, you may run your cmd as following (within Task contents or ConEmu's Command line)

```
cmd /k ver & GitShowBranch /i
```

PS. File `GitShowBranch` exists in ConEmu's distro, but you may see it [online](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/blob/daily/Release/ConEmu/GitShowBranch.cmd).

Comment: Is there any way to customize the branch name? By default its the local name plus an elipsis plus the remote name. WAY TOO MUCH! I just want the local branch name.

Comment: Can't detect ellipsis, but can drop tail from first found dot.

Answer (score 8):

Yes there is a way. Install [git bash](http://www.git-scm.com/downloads), then in ConEmu settings, under the "ComSpec" section set the Explicit executable to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`.

This runs a bash shell session, and gives you a fully resizable window, with the git tab completion and current working branch prompt.

Comment: It's definitely the best way to do it (there is even a topic for that http://superuser.com/questions/454380/git-bash-here-in-conemu)

Comment: This does nothing. There must be something else that need to be done.

Answer (score 8):

Change the `specified named task` to `{Bash::Git}` in Settings -> Startup and you'll have branch name showing up.

[image: Settings screeshot]

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the situation is:

[image: showing branch name]

I know `sh.exe` can do this but needed to check if it is in the `Git\bin` folder and have access by only writing `sh` in command line.

First I saw `sh.exe` in `Git\bin` folder but wanted to see if I can execute on command line. To see it I checked environment vars using by `echo %path%`
It was complicated to see if there is. I used powershell script and there is :)

I would have execute sh in command line too :)))

*Refrences:*

- powershell [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1#examples)
- [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348506/split-string-with-powershell-and-do-something-with-each-token) environment variables ([path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114985/echo-path-on-separate-lines))

*Codes:*

```
echo %path%
($env:Path).split(";") | where ({$_ -like "*Git*"})
```