# Is it possible to read console's screen buffer on windows and output it to somewhere with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, windows-console

If possible, I'd like to build an windows console interface like Console2 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) or ConEmu (https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) with node.js. The application will access and read Console's screenbuffer and output it to somewhere, back to console output buffer or node-webkit window. With Blessed (https://github.com/chjj/blessed) I can output to screen buffer, but I'm not sure how to read screen buffer.

For example, if I do "git pull" in the node app, it will create a child process and send the command to it. The process will run the command and output the result to the screen buffer. I want to capture it and output back to my node app.

I can see that there are a few node terminal app. So it seems to be possible to create a console interface, if only I can access the screen buffer of a cmd.exe process. Anyone with experience or knowledge, please help me! I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: ConEmu can integrate into any window (work inside as a child). Are you sure you need this pain with piping?

Comment: Hi Maximus, I'm a big fan of ConEmu and use it everyday. It will be fun to do with node, but also there are a few little things I'd like to have. For example, I want show git branch to the prompt.

Comment: I see no problem with 'git branch'. Actually, I use see it in cmd and Far prompt ;) [screenshot on tumblr](http://conemu.tumblr.com/post/67265627918/git-branch-and-changes-count-in-plain-cmd-prompt)

Comment: Take a look at this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21293439/1405560