# echo output is unexpected

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I am trying to print path using echo on PowerShell, but the output is `%Path%`.

```
PS C:\> echo %Path%
%Path%
```

Could you tell me how to go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Echo %path% on separate lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114985/echo-path-on-separate-lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%Path% is a commandline variable, which is not supported in PowerShell. You'd need to use the appropriate environment variable:

```
echo $env:Path
```

Answer (score 4):

In PowerShell environment variables are expanded via the `env` scope:

```
PS C:\> $env:Path
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;...
```

`%xxx%` variables are a CMD thing.