# Why does the DOS "path" command repeat entries?

Tags: path, dos

(WinXP Home SP2)

### path command output from CLI

[image]

### Path variable value from My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables

[image]

Comment: How you are opening this cli? is it a batch file?

Comment: Just going into the command line and typing path. I added a new line after each entry for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing magical about the PATH environment variable that prevents duplicate entries.

Typically the individual paths are added to PATH via some type of installer, though they can also be added manually. It is the job of the installer to make sure duplicates are not entered. Some installers are lazy and don't bother to check to see if a given path already exists prior to insertion.

The initial value for PATH is built by combining the System and User environment settings from the registry.

Often times a batch process will attempt to augment the path with an additional entry, if and only if it does not already exist. [How to check if directory exists in %PATH%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141344/how-to-check-if-directory-exists-in-path) is a popular SO batch file question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the PATH variable itself is contained in the PATH