# How to append to Path if not already appended

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I want to append `%MYSQL_HOME%\bin` and `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin` to the `Path` system environment variable on Windows, but I want to append these **only if** they are not already appended. How do I do it on the command prompt or in a batch script?

Comment: There are many simple solutions, but nearly all have the potential to fail, depending on the existing PATH value, as well as the path to be appended. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8046515/1012053 for an exhaustive list of issues, as well as a robust solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
path|find /i "%MYSQL_HOME%\bin"    >nul || set path=%path%;%MYSQL_HOME%\bin
path|find /i "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin" >nul || set path=%path%;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%a IN (skipsql skipcat) DO SET "%%a="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('"echo %path:;=&ECHO(%"') DO (
IF /i "%%a"=="%MYSQL_HOME%\bin" SET skipsql=Y
IF /i "%%a"=="%CATALINA_HOME%\bin" SET skipcat=Y
)
IF NOT DEFINED skipsql SET "path=%path%;%MYSQL_HOME%\bin"
IF NOT DEFINED skipcat SET "path=%path%;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin"
ECHO new path=%path%
GOTO :EOF
```

This should work for you. Remember that it will only work for the current instance of `cmd` - it's not transmitted to existing or future `cmd` instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in ("%MYSQL_HOME%\bin" "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin") do (
   if "!path:%%~a=!" equ "!path!" set "path=!path!;%%a"
)

ECHO New path=%path%
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a convoluted approach using a temp file:

```
set PATH_BACKUP=%PATH%
path | findstr "%MYSQL_HOME%\bin" > _tmp.txt
path=%PATH%;%MYSQL_HOME%\bin
for /f %%i in (_tmp.txt) do path=%PATH_BACKUP%
del _tmp.txt

set PATH_BACKUP=%PATH%
path | findstr "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin" > _tmp.txt
path=%PATH%;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin
for /f %%i in (_tmp.txt) do path=%PATH_BACKUP%
del _tmp.txt
```

Replace _tmp.txt with some other throw-away filename if need be.

This is for a batch file.  If using from the command line, replace %%i with %i.

Answer (score 0):

Path consists of two parts, system path and user path. To add directory to user path, first get user path and system path separately. Then use "set" and "setx" commands for setting the path. "set" command sets the environment locally and "setx" globally. At end you can combine the user path and system path back to use the path locally.

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%N in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKCU\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%N" == "Path" call set "UserPath=%%P"
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%N in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v "Path" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%N" == "Path" call set "SystemPath=%%P"
echo ;%UserPath%; | find /i ";%DirToAppend%;" > nul || setx Path "%DirToAppend%;%UserPath%"
echo ;%UserPath%; | find /i ";%DirToAppend%;" > nul || set UserPath=%DirToAppend%;%UserPath%
echo ;%UserPath%; | find /i ";%Dir2ToAppend%;" > nul || setx Path "%Dir2ToAppend%;%UserPath%"
echo ;%UserPath%; | find /i ";%Dir2ToAppend%;" > nul || set UserPath=%Dir2ToAppend%;%UserPath%
set Path=%SystemPath%;%UserPath%
```