# Setting the Path Only Once

Tags: batch-file, scripting, cmd

**Question:** What is simple, reliable way to add a folder to the system path in a batch script **only once** no matter how many times I run the script?

I need to add a folder to the path permanently. But I only want to add it one time, even if I run the script many times.

**Attempts:** I am comfortable adding the folder to the path in the environment and the registry:

```
SETX /m PATH "%PATH%;%MyFolder%"
SET PATH=PATH;%MyFolder%
```

Yet I need to guarantee it will **not** keep adding the same folder to the path variable every time it runs. My first thought is to compare strings to check if it already contains the folder, *but I need help with the syntax:*

```
REM If the PATH folder does not contain the folder already
IF NOT %MyFolder%==%PATH% (
  REM Add the folder to the path
)
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [How to check if directory exists in %PATH%?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/141344/1012053). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8046515/1012053) for a robust method to detect an existing path.

Comment: @dbenham Your answer is a big help. I'm using `inPath` to do the heavy lifting now and it works great. I'm not sure what to do about answering this question, though...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple routine that only checks if the **exact** path is already listed and if it is not found, adds it to the PATH.

```
@echo off
call :AppendMachinePATH "%MyFolder%"
exit /b 0

:AppendMachinePATH <Path to Add>
for %%A in ("%PATH:;=" "%") do if /i "%%~A"=="%~1" exit /b 1
setx /m PATH "%PATH%;%MyFolder%"
set "PATH=%PATH%;%MyFolder%"
exit /b 0
```

<sub>(Written from memory, not tested)</sub>