# Upgrade / Uninstall NodeJS on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, uninstallation

Somehow node version v0.12.2 got installed on my Windows machine and I'd like to upgrade to a newer version, however, it is not in the "Add or Remove Programs" menu.

When I try to install node from the Windows MSI, I get the standard [windows 1603](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/834484/you-receive-an-error-1603-a-fatal-error-occurred-during-installation-e) error (below), which I am assuming means windows thinks that this application is already installed.

> MSI (s) (64:84): Windows Installer installed the
>   product. Product Name: Node.js. Product Version: 6.11.0. Product
>   Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Node.js Foundation. Installation success
>   or error status: 1603.

Any ideas?  I've tried lots of things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602808/uninstall-node-js-windows-10) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows) with no luck.

I am trying to install an npm package that depends on a higher version of node and striking out.

Comment: Do you have any Adobe software installed by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed [Node Version Manager for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) and it recognized this installation of Node. I was able to install alternate versions of node from here.  It also recognized my current installation of node and was able to facilitate an "uninstallation" without going through the windows "add/remove programs" feature.

Comment: Yes, it will work, but it's a workaround (a good one in fact). It doesn't solve the main problem of removing the old Node.js from installed programs on Windows.

Comment: part of my problem was the old nodejs didn't show up in the installed programs on windows so I had to find a different way to remove it...nvm was able to remove since it recognized the installation as valid.  Not sure I understand.

Answer (score 8):

Man, I had this same issue a long time ago and it was really a pain to discover what I should do. Just download the .msi related to the version installed on your machine from here:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Execute the downloaded .msi, and from there, choose to uninstall.