# How to dynamically split a string using delims ;

Tags: batch-file

I wish to dynamically break a string using ; as a delimitter
*C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;*

and then find if a path already exist. If C:\windows\system32 is already in the string then it should raise a flag.

Please help

Comment: Where is the problem in your code?

Comment: Besides the "'Pretty print' windows..." Q&A, you should also look at [How to check if directory exists in %PATH%](http://stackoverflow.com/q/141344/1012053)

Answer (score 1):

A simple, *not bulletproof*, method may look something like this:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "FLAG="
FOR %%A IN ("%PATH:;=";"%") DO IF /I %%A=="%SystemRoot%\system32" SET "FLAG=T"
IF DEFINED FLAG ECHO The location exists as an entry in %%PATH%%
TIMEOUT -1
```

*It will work correctly if you do not have paths with `;` or `"`.*

**Edit**
If you are unlucky enough to have entries using double quotes, you could use a slightly different method which replaces each semi-colon with a line feed character:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "FLAG="
SET LF=^
%FLAG%
%FLAG%
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ("%PATH:;=!LF!%"
) DO IF /I "%%A"=="%SystemRoot%\system32" SET "FLAG=T"
IF DEFINED FLAG ECHO The location exists as an entry in %%PATH%%
TIMEOUT -1
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of FOR %%A IN ("%PATH:;=";"%")

Comment: `"%PATH:;=";"%"` places each entry of path into doublequotes, _(it replaces each semi-colon with a double-quote, semi-colon, doublequote sequence and adds an opening double-quote to the first entry and closing double-quote to the last entry)_. The for loop then separates each entry because the semi-colon, `;`, is one of it's default delimiters. Each entry is attached to `%%A` which is then compared against your target string using the case insensitive `IF` option, `/I`.

Comment: But `;` is also a valid character in a directory, like `PATH="C:\my;dir\";C:\windows`

Comment: I'm aware of that @jeb, however the stipulation of a semi-colon delimiter means that it is unnercessary to provide for that scenario. _You need to also bear in mind that my examples use %PATH%, the OP on the other hand has not._

Answer (score 0):

complement prior answer, also

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (^"!path:^;^=^
% Do NOT remove this line %
!^") do IF /I "%%a"=="%SystemRoot%\system32" SET "FLAG=T"
IF DEFINED FLAG ECHO The location exists as an entry in %%PATH%%
```

this can handle paths with quotes.