# Calculating within a FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, variables, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to set up scheduled tasks for all the machines in our network. So they don't all have the same start time I edit the XML file to use a random time. The changing the XML works fine, but as soon as I put a For loop around it to use servers.txt I get an error message: "+10 was unexpected at this time."

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (servers.txt) do (

set file=original.xml
set insertline=9
SET /a uur=(%RANDOM%*6/32768)+10
SET /a minuut=(%RANDOM%*50/32768)+10
set output=output.XLM

(for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v "##" ^< "%file%"') do (
    if "%%~a"=="%insertline%" (
    echo ^<StartBoundary^>2018-12-17T%uur%:%minuut%:43.9766025^<^/StartBoundary^>
    REM ECHO.%%b
    ) ELSE (
    echo.%%b
    )
    )) > %output%

SchTasks /Create /S \\%%i /RU username /RP password /XML output.XLM /TN task_name

)
```

Comment: Oh by the way, the reason I use the +10 is that random numbers below 10 only give a single digit. I suspect that could give an issue with the time format. So it should give a number between 10 and 59.

uur = hour
minuut = minute

Comment: try with [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: tried delayed expansion, same error :(

Comment: Delayed expansion is really needed here, but it's not the reason for `+10 was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673340/modifying-the-path-variable-from-batch/53685829#53685829) (along with [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-in-batch-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028))

Answer (score 1):

The closing parentheses in your `set` commands are closing the `for` loop too early.

Here are two possible ways to overcome that:

```
SET /a "uur=(%RANDOM%*6/32768)+10"
SET /a minuut=(%RANDOM%*50/32768^)+10
```

The first one secures the `)` by enclosing the whole assignment in quotes, the second escapes the `)` (with a caret `^`). (you should consistently use ONE of that possibilities throughout your whole script - I'd recommend the first one (with quotes))

Another failure: `%RANDOM%` will give you the same value each time within a command block (use [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-in-batch-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) to overcome that.

Later in the script, you have the same issue with the `file` and `insertline` variables. So also change from `%file%` and `%insertline%` to `!file!` and `!insertline!`.

Comment: @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (servers.txt) do (

set file=original.xml
set insertline=9
SET /a "uur=(!RANDOM!*6/32768)+10"
SET /a "minuut=(!RANDOM!*50/32768)+10"
set output=output.XLM

echo !uur!:!minuut!
)'

That works, but when I also use the 2nd loop: The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: please edit your new code into your question; A comment doesn't have format capabilities and leaves your code nearly unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I think overwriting `output.xml` is intended to create a new task from the template with different (random) StartBoundary.

But all the constants (re-defined inside the code block) should be moved outside to the front.

As the inner for has only the if/else command, one set of parentheses is superfluous.

Proper indenting helps to keep overview of the code.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\12\17\SO_53814701.cmd
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set file=original.xml
set insertline=9
set output=output.XLM

for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (servers.txt) do (
    SET /a "uur=(!RANDOM!*6/32768)+10"
    SET /a "minuut=(!RANDOM!*50/32768)+10"
    (   for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in (
            'find /n /v "##" ^< "%file%"'
        ) do if "%%~a"=="%insertline%" (
            echo ^<StartBoundary^>2018-12-17T%uur%:%minuut%:43.9766025^<^/StartBoundary^>
            REM ECHO.%%b
        ) ELSE (
            echo.%%b
        )
    ) > %output%
    SchTasks /Create /S \\%%i /RU username /RP password /XML output.XLM /TN task_name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... I changed something and now it works...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (servers.txt) do (

set file=original.xlm
set insertline=9
SET /a "uur=(!RANDOM!*6/32768^)+10"
SET /a "minuut=(!RANDOM!*50/32768^)+10"
set output=output.XLM
echo !uur!:!minuut!
(for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v "##" ^< "!file!"') do (
if "%%~a"=="!insertline!" (
echo ^<StartBoundary^>2018-12-17T!uur!:!minuut!:43.9766025^<^/StartBoundary^>
REM ECHO.%%b
) ELSE (
echo.%%b
)
)) > !output!

SchTasks /Create /S \\%%i /RU username /RP password /XML output.XLM /TN task_name

)
)
)
```

I think it was changing all the % for ! within the FOR